# Python: Split NumPy array based on values in the array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split

I have one big array:

```
[(1.0, 3.0, 1, 427338.4297000002, 4848489.4332)
 (1.0, 3.0, 2, 427344.7937000003, 4848482.0692)
 (1.0, 3.0, 3, 427346.4297000002, 4848472.7469) ...,
 (1.0, 1.0, 7084, 427345.2709999997, 4848796.592)
 (1.0, 1.0, 7085, 427352.9277999997, 4848790.9351)
 (1.0, 1.0, 7086, 427359.16060000006, 4848787.4332)]
```

I want to split this array into multiple arrays based on the 2nd value in the array (3.0, 3.0, 3.0...1.0,1.0,10).

Every time the 2nd value changes, I want a new array, so basically each new array has the same 2nd value. I've looked this up on Stack Overflow and know of the command

```
np.split(array, number)
```

but I'm not trying to split the array into a certain number of arrays, but rather by a value. How would I be able to split the array in the way specified above?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There is also Pandas's `groupby`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622888/how-to-plot-2-lines-based-on-the-value-not-column

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can find the indices where the values differ by using [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`numpy.diff`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) on the first column:

```
>>> arr = np.array([(1.0, 3.0, 1, 427338.4297000002, 4848489.4332),
 (1.0, 3.0, 2, 427344.7937000003, 4848482.0692),
 (1.0, 3.0, 3, 427346.4297000002, 4848472.7469),
 (1.0, 1.0, 7084, 427345.2709999997, 4848796.592),
 (1.0, 1.0, 7085, 427352.9277999997, 4848790.9351),
 (1.0, 1.0, 7086, 427359.16060000006, 4848787.4332)])
>>> np.split(arr, np.where(np.diff(arr[:,1]))[0]+1)
[array([[  1.00000000e+00,   3.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
          4.27338430e+05,   4.84848943e+06],
       [  1.00000000e+00,   3.00000000e+00,   2.00000000e+00,
          4.27344794e+05,   4.84848207e+06],
       [  1.00000000e+00,   3.00000000e+00,   3.00000000e+00,
          4.27346430e+05,   4.84847275e+06]]),
 array([[  1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   7.08400000e+03,
          4.27345271e+05,   4.84879659e+06],
       [  1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   7.08500000e+03,
          4.27352928e+05,   4.84879094e+06],
       [  1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   7.08600000e+03,
          4.27359161e+05,   4.84878743e+06]])]
```

**Explanation:**

Here first we are going to fetch the items in the second 2 column:

```
>>> arr[:,1]
array([ 3.,  3.,  3.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

Now to find out where the items actually change we can use `numpy.diff`:

```
>>> np.diff(arr[:,1])
array([ 0.,  0., -2.,  0.,  0.])
```

Any thing non-zero means that the item next to it was different, we can use `numpy.where` to find the indices of non-zero items and then add 1 to it because the actual index of such item is one more than the returned index:

```
>>> np.where(np.diff(arr[:,1]))[0]+1
array([3])
```

Comment: I get an IndexError: Too many indices for array. Do you know what the issue is? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @whent1991 Can you post the actual array?

Comment: The one I posted is the actual array, but it is a huge array so there's "..." in the middle of the array.

Comment: Hi, this solution worked great, but could you explain what the (np.diff(arr[:,1])))[0]+1 does? The syntax confuses me a bit as I am quite new to Python. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @whent1991 Added some explanation.

Comment: Any way to apply this to strings?

Comment: Very useful technique!

Comment: Thanks very much. Indeed, this is the best answer to this issue.