# How to Plot 2 lines based on the value not column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a data set:

```
ReviewDate_year,ReviewDate_month,Sales
 2010,11,1
 2011,02,2
 2011,11,1
 2011,12,6
 2012,01,11
 2012,02,8
 2012,03,3
 2012,04,1
 2012,05,8
 2012,06,3
 2012,07,1
 2012,08,2
 2012,09,1
 2012,11,1
 2012,12,8
 2013,01,2
 2013,02,2
 2013,03,4
 2013,04,4
 2013,05,7
 2013,06,5
 2013,07,6
 2013,08,4
 2013,09,4
 2013,10,5
 2013,11,3
 2013,12,5
 2014,01,9
 2014,02,4
 2014,03,8
 2014,04,7
 2014,05,3
 2014,06,7
 2014,07,1
```

How do I plot Sales by month and different year in different line

I can certainly do it by year

```
df_2013 = df_monthlycount[df_monthlycount['ReviewDate_year'] == 2013]
df_2014 = df_monthlycount[df_monthlycount['ReviewDate_year'] == 2014]

df_2013.plot(x='ReviewDate_month',y='ProductId')

plt.show()
```

but how can I make lines of different year in a single chart?

Comment: Data shaping without pandas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31863083/python-split-numpy-array-based-on-values-in-the-array

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465645/plotting-results-of-pandas-groupby

Answer (score 4):

You can use `groupby` plot. Instead of creating one `ax` for each group, you can specify an `ax` and have everything plotted on that `ax`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm

ax = plt.subplot(111)
df[df.ReviewDate_year.isin([2012,2013])].groupby('ReviewDate_year').plot(y='Sales', x='ReviewDate_month', kind='line', ax=ax)
L = plt.legend()
_ = [plt.setp(item, 'text', T) for item, T in zip(L.texts, ['2012','2013'])]
_ = ax.set_xticks(df.ReviewDate_month.unique())
```

[image]