# Is there any numpy group by function?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there any function in numpy to group this array down below by the first column?

I couldn't find any good answer over the internet..

```
>>> a
array([[  1, 275],
       [  1, 441],
       [  1, 494],
       [  1, 593],
       [  2, 679],
       [  2, 533],
       [  2, 686],
       [  3, 559],
       [  3, 219],
       [  3, 455],
       [  4, 605],
       [  4, 468],
       [  4, 692],
       [  4, 613]])
```

Wanted output:

```
array([[[275, 441, 494, 593]],
       [[679, 533, 686]],
       [[559, 219, 455]],
       [[605, 468, 692, 613]]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 107):

Inspired by [Eelco Hoogendoorn's library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38015063/1488055), but without his library, and using the fact that the first column of your array is always increasing (if not, sort first with `a = a[a[:, 0].argsort()]`)

```
>>> np.split(a[:,1], np.unique(a[:, 0], return_index=True)[1][1:])
[array([275, 441, 494, 593]),
 array([679, 533, 686]),
 array([559, 219, 455]),
 array([605, 468, 692, 613])]
```

I didn't "timeit" ([EDIT] see below) but this is probably the faster way to achieve the question :

- No python native loop
- Result lists are numpy arrays, in case you need to make other numpy operations on them, no new conversion will be needed
- Complexity looks O(n) (with sort it goes O(n log(n))

[EDIT sept 2021] I ran timeit on my Macbook M1, for a table of 10k random integers. The duration is for 1000 calls.

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(5, size=(10000, 2))  # 5 different "groups"

# Only the sort
>>> a = a[a[:, 0].argsort()]
⏱ 116.9 ms

# Group by on the already sorted table
>>> np.split(a[:, 1], np.unique(a[:, 0], return_index=True)[1][1:])
⏱ 35.5 ms

# Total sort + groupby
>>> a = a[a[:, 0].argsort()]
>>> np.split(a[:, 1], np.unique(a[:, 0], return_index=True)[1][1:])
⏱ 153.0 ms 

# With numpy-indexed package (cf Eelco answer)
>>> npi.group_by(a[:, 0]).split(a[:, 1])
⏱ 353.3 ms

# With pandas (cf Piotr answer)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=["key", "val"]) # no timer for this line
>>> df.groupby("key").val.apply(pd.Series.tolist) 
⏱ 362.3 ms

# With defaultdict, the python native way (cf Piotr answer)
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
for key, val in a:
    d[key].append(val)
⏱ 3543.2 ms

# With numpy_groupies (cf Michael answer)
>>> aggregate(a[:,0], a[:,1], "array", fill_value=[])
⏱ 376.4 ms
```

Second timeit scenario, with 500 different groups instead of 5.
I'm surprised about pandas, I ran several times, but it just behave badly in this scenario.

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(500, size=(10000, 2))

just the sort  141.1 ms
already_sorted 392.0 ms
sort+groupby   542.4 ms
pandas        2695.8 ms
numpy-indexed  800.6 ms
defaultdict   3707.3 ms
numpy_groupies 836.7 ms
```

[EDIT] I improved the answer thanks to
[ns63sr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53859634/1488055) and [Behzad Shayegh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13146793/behzad-shayegh) (cf comment)
Thanks also [TMBailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16327476/tmbailey) for noticing complexity of argsort is n log(n).

Comment: If you have to do the sort, won't that bump the complexity up to O(n log n) if the items are not already sorted?

Comment: I've put some effort lately in order to estimate if it's possible to create something faster than total sort + groupby. Indeed, total sort (`a = a[a[:, 0].argsort()]`) is an issue. First reason, it's O(n log n). Secondly, it consumes 80% of performing time. It's unlikely `np.argsort` going to be optimised soon by developers of `numpy` or `numba`. Hence, it's possible to speed up remaining 20% only. The main direction of further optimisation is to replace `np.unique` with `np.bincount` which could be improved even more if it's redesigned in `numba`. Remark: bincount won't work on large IDs.

Comment: What's more, I wouldn't recommend to use `np.split` within design of OP's code because it creates an empty pythonic `list` and calls `list.append` on each slice of numpyic array [under the hood](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70797158/3044825).

Comment: Concerning the efficiency of Pandas, actually, in your results, the major part of the time is due to the `apply` and `tolist`  operations. The `groupby` itself is very efficient. I am not able to reproduce exactly your stats, but with the same example, sort + split is about 350µs. Pandas without the list conversion is 213µs. Moreover, the pandas groupby operation seems to be insensitive to N. To get the groups, you can use the `get_group` method of `DataFrameGroupBy`, but this one is slow. [Here are the results](https://github.com/gVallverdu/cookbook/blob/master/numpy_groupby.ipynb).

Answer (score 47):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) aims to fill this gap in numpy. All operations in numpy-indexed are fully vectorized, and no O(n^2) algorithms were harmed during the making of this library.

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
npi.group_by(a[:, 0]).split(a[:, 1])
```

Note that it is usually more efficient to directly compute relevant properties over such groups (ie, group_by(keys).mean(values)), rather than first splitting into a list / jagged array.

Comment: Thanks . The way I meant it is that using On2 algorithms is intrinsically painful, even to said algorithm itself. But yeah I guess you have to assume the On2 algorithm is also self aware about it's inferiority for the sentence to make sense..

Comment: Note that this implementation of `group_by` changes the order of the output groups so that they are sorted by the values of the parameter of the `group_by`. Pandas' `groupby` keeps the original order.

Comment: In case the group keys are integers so that `len(set(group_keys)) == max(group_keys) + 1 and min(group_keys) == 0` then you can restore the original order by manually indexing the returned array by the `groupby` parameter value again later though. `(_, result) = npi.group_by(group_keys).mean(values[:, :]); result = result[group_keys, :]`

Answer (score 28):

Numpy is not very handy here because the desired output is not an array of integers (it is an array of list objects).

I suggest either the pure Python way...

```
from collections import defaultdict

%%timeit
d = defaultdict(list)
for key, val in a:
    d[key].append(val)
10.7 µs ± 156 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

# result:
defaultdict(list,
        {1: [275, 441, 494, 593],
         2: [679, 533, 686],
         3: [559, 219, 455],
         4: [605, 468, 692, 613]})
```

...or the pandas way:

```
import pandas as pd

%%timeit
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=["key", "val"])
df.groupby("key").val.apply(pd.Series.tolist)
979 µs ± 3.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# result:
key
1    [275, 441, 494, 593]
2         [679, 533, 686]
3         [559, 219, 455]
4    [605, 468, 692, 613]
Name: val, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 15):

```
n = np.unique(a[:,0])
np.array( [ list(a[a[:,0]==i,1]) for i in n] )
```

outputs:

```
array([[275, 441, 494, 593], [679, 533, 686], [559, 219, 455],
       [605, 468, 692, 613]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: to have exactly the same answer, as he wants `array([[x] for x in [ list(a[a[:,0]==i,1]) for i in n]])`

Comment: yes, your solution returns what he asked for. But I just assumed that he actually wanted an array of lists and not a useless array of lists of lists containing a single element

Comment: Note that this solution requires O(n^2) operations, making it very inefficient.

Comment: use `np.unique` instead of `unique` to clearify your code.

Comment: works perfectly. though I don't understand what does the "1" play role into the `list(a[a[:,0]==i,1])` statement

Comment: @partizanos, because it's the items in the 1st column that should be grouped.

Answer (score 11):

Simplifying the [answer of Vincent J](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43094244/4395722) and considering the comment of  HS-nebula one can use `return_index = True` instead of `return_counts = True` and get rid of the `cumsum`:

```
np.split(a[:,1], np.unique(a[:,0], return_index = True)[1])[1:]
```

Output

```
[array([275, 441, 494, 593]),
 array([679, 533, 686]),
 array([559, 219, 455]),
 array([605, 468, 692, 613])]
```

Comment: What if the first column isn’t sorted? Can we somehow combine sorting it and creating the groups?

Comment: @Vidak `a.sort(axis=0)` would sort the array inplace by its first column (assuming that indices are stored there)

Comment: This answer doesn't produce the correct output. It works if you set `idx = a[:,0]` so that the full code is `np.split(a[:,1], np.unique(a[:,0], return_index = True)[1])[1:]`

Comment: Great solution, but it has a limitation. This doesn't work if there is a missing index, (let's say 2). It will only return a list that is 3 items long, but you will then not be able to access by index into the new list as there would be some indices missing. Any way to return an empty list for the non-present indices?

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but anyways. If you plan to not only group the arrays, but also want to do operations on them like sum, mean and so on, and you're doing this with speed in mind, you also might want to consider [numpy_groupies](https://github.com/ml31415/numpy-groupies). All those group operations are optimized and jitted with numba. They easily outperform the other mentioned solutions.

```py
from numpy_groupies.aggregate_numpy import aggregate
aggregate(a[:,0], a[:,1], "array", fill_value=[])
>>> array([array([], dtype=int64), array([275, 441, 494, 593]),
           array([679, 533, 686]), array([559, 219, 455]),
           array([605, 468, 692, 613])], dtype=object)
aggregate(a[:,0], a[:,1], "sum")
>>> array([   0, 1803, 1898, 1233, 2378])
```

Answer (score 2):

It becomes pretty apparent that `a = a[a[:, 0].argsort()]` is a bottleneck of all the competetive grouping algorithms, big thanks to [Vincent J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1488055/vincent-j) for clarifying this. Over 80% of processing time are just blown up on this `argsort` method and there's no easy way to replace or optimise it. `numba` package allows to speed up a lot of algorithms and, hopefully, `argsort` will attract any efforts in the future. The **remaining part** of grouping can be improved significantly assuming indices of first column are small.

### TL;DR

The **remaining part** of majority of grouping methods contains `np.unique` method which is quite slow and excessive in cases values of groups are small. It's more efficient to replace it with `np.bincount` which could be later improved in `numba`.
There are some results of how the **remaining part** could be improved:

```
def _custom_return(unique_id, a, split_idx, return_groups):
    '''Choose if you want to also return unique ids'''
    if return_groups:
        return unique_id, np.split(a[:,1], split_idx)
    else: 
        return np.split(a[:,1], split_idx)

def numpy_groupby_index(a, return_groups=False):
    '''Code refactor of method of Vincent J'''
    u, idx = np.unique(a[:,0], return_index=True) 
    return _custom_return(u, a, idx[1:], return_groups)

def numpy_groupby_counts(a, return_groups=False):
    '''Use cumsum of counts instead of index'''
    u, counts = np.unique(a[:,0], return_counts=True)
    idx = np.cumsum(counts)
    return _custom_return(u, a, idx[:-1], return_groups)

def numpy_groupby_diff(a, return_groups=False):
    '''No use of any np.unique options'''
    u = np.unique(a[:,0])
    idx = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(a[:,0])) + 1
    return _custom_return(u, a, idx, return_groups)

def numpy_groupby_bins(a, return_groups=False):  
    '''Replace np.unique by np.bincount'''
    bins = np.bincount(a[:,0])
    nonzero_bins_idx = bins != 0
    nonzero_bins = bins[nonzero_bins_idx]
    idx = np.cumsum(nonzero_bins[:-1])
    return _custom_return(np.flatnonzero(nonzero_bins_idx), a, idx, return_groups)

def numba_groupby_bins(a, return_groups=False):  
    '''Replace np.bincount by numba_bincount'''
    bins = numba_bincount(a[:,0])
    nonzero_bins_idx = bins != 0
    nonzero_bins = bins[nonzero_bins_idx]
    idx = np.cumsum(nonzero_bins[:-1])
    return _custom_return(np.flatnonzero(nonzero_bins_idx), a, idx, return_groups)
```

So `numba_bincount` works in the same way as `np.bincount` and it's defined like so:

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def _numba_bincount(a, counts, m):
    for i in range(m):
        counts[a[i]] += 1

def numba_bincount(arr): #just a refactor of Python count
    M = np.max(arr)
    counts = np.zeros(M + 1, dtype=int)
    _numba_bincount(arr, counts, len(arr))
    return counts
```

### Usage:

```
a = np.array([[1,275],[1,441],[1,494],[1,593],[2,679],[2,533],[2,686],[3,559],[3,219],[3,455],[4,605],[4,468],[4,692],[4,613]])
a = a[a[:, 0].argsort()]
>>> numpy_groupby_index(a, return_groups=False)
[array([275, 441, 494, 593]),
 array([679, 533, 686]),
 array([559, 219, 455]),
 array([605, 468, 692, 613])]
>>> numpy_groupby_index(a, return_groups=True)
(array([1, 2, 3, 4]),
 [array([275, 441, 494, 593]),
  array([679, 533, 686]),
  array([559, 219, 455]),
  array([605, 468, 692, 613])])
```

### Perfmormance tests

It takes ~30 seconds to sort 100M items on my computer (with 10 distincts IDs). Let's test how much time will methods of the remaining part take to run:

```
%matplotlib inline
benchit.setparams(rep=3)

sizes = [3*10**(i//2) if i%2 else 10**(i//2) for i in range(17)]
N = sizes[-1]
x1 = np.random.randint(0,10, size=N)
x2 = np.random.normal(loc=500, scale=200, size=N).astype(int)
a = np.transpose([x1, x2])

arr = a[a[:, 0].argsort()]
fns = [numpy_groupby_index, numpy_groupby_counts, numpy_groupby_diff, numpy_groupby_bins, numba_groupby_bins]
in_ = {s/1000000: (arr[:s], ) for s in sizes}
t = benchit.timings(fns, in_, multivar=True, input_name='Millions of events')
t.plot(logx=True, figsize=(12, 6), fontsize=14)
```

[image]

No doubt `numba`-powered bincount is a new winner of datasets that contains small IDs. It helps to reduce grouping of sorted data ~5 times which is ~10% of total runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I used np.unique() followed by np.extract()

```
unique = np.unique(a[:, 0:1])
answer = []
for element in unique:
    present = a[:,0]==element
    answer.append(np.extract(present,a[:,-1]))
print (answer)
```

`[array([275, 441, 494, 593]), array([679, 533, 686]), array([559, 219, 455]), array([605, 468, 692, 613])]`

Answer (score 1):

given X as array of items you want to be grouped and y (1D array) as corresponding groups, following function does the grouping with *numpy*:

```
def groupby(X, y):
    y = np.asarray(y)
    X = np.asarray(X)
    y_uniques = np.unique(y)
    return [X[y==yi] for yi in y_uniques]
```

So, `groupby(a[:,1], a[:,0])` returns
`[array([275, 441, 494, 593]), array([679, 533, 686]), array([559, 219, 455]), array([605, 468, 692, 613])]`

Answer (score 1):

We might also find it useful to generate a `dict`:

```
def groupby(X): 
    X = np.asarray(X) 
    x_uniques = np.unique(X) 
    return {xi:X[X==xi] for xi in x_uniques}
```

Let's try it out:

```
X=[1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,9,1,1,1]
groupby(X)                                                                                                      
Out[9]: 
{1: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
 2: array([2, 2]),
 3: array([3, 3, 3, 3]),
 4: array([4]),
 5: array([5]),
 6: array([6]),
 7: array([7, 7]),
 8: array([8]),
 9: array([9, 9])}
```

Note this by itself is not super compelling - but if we make `X` an `object` or `namedtuple` and then provide a `groupby` function it becomes more interesting. Will put that in later.

Comment: When you work with numpy, going back to python dicts is in general a huge decrease in speed. If you work with larger arrays, stick with numpy functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach suggested by [Ashwini Chaudhary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31863083/python-split-numpy-array-based-on-values-in-the-array#:%7E:text=created%20(oldest%20first)-,25,1%0Aarray(%5B3%5D),-Share) may be what you are looking for. Putting it in a simple function

```
def np_groupby(x, index):
    return np.split(x, np.where(np.diff(x[:,index]))[0]+1)
```

x = numpy array

index = column index

[0] + 1 according to Ashwini, *...any thing non-zero means that the item next to it was different, we can use `numpy.where` to find the indices of non-zero items and then add 1 to it because the actual index of such item is one more than the returned index; ...numpy.diff is used to find out where the items actually change.*

Answer (score 0):

I use this swiss-knife function that does group-by, and optionally apply and transform. It simplifies my code a lot:

````py
def group_by(by, func=lambda idx: idx, transform=False, equal_nan=True):
    """
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/77150915
    Groups by the unique values of `by`, calls `func` on each group of
    indices and returns the combined results as a numpy array.
    If `transform=True` the output has as many rows as x (like pandas "transform"),
    and as many rows as unique values in x otherwise (like pandas "apply"),
    ```
    # Examples:
    x = np.array([1, 3, 1, 2, 3])
    y = np.array([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
    print(group_by(x)) # [array([0, 2]) array([3]) array([1, 4])]
    means = group_by(x, lambda idx: np.mean(y[idx]))
    print(means) # [4.  2.  2.5]
    means = group_by(x, lambda idx: np.mean(y[idx]), transform=True)
    print(means) # [4.  2.5 4.  2.  2.5]
    mins, maxs = group_by(x, lambda idx: [np.min(y[idx]), np.max(y[idx])]).T
    print(mins, maxs) # [3 2 1] [5 2 4]
    for idx in group_by(x):
        print(x[idx[0]], y[idx]) # 1 [5 3]; 2 [2]; 3 [4 1]
    ```
    """
    _, invs, cnts = np.unique(
        by, return_counts=True, return_inverse=True, axis=0, equal_nan=equal_nan
    )
    idxs = np.split(np.argsort(by), np.cumsum(cnts)[:-1])
    out = [func(idx) for idx in idxs]
    if transform:
        out = [out[invs[i]] for i in range(len(by))]
    try:
        out = np.array(out)
    except:
        out = np.array(out, dtype=object)
    return out




x = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 7, 3, 2])
y = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

print(group_by(x)) # [array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 7]), array([6]), array([4, 5])]
print(group_by(x, lambda idx: y[idx].mean())) # [1.  5.  6.  4.5]
print(group_by(x, lambda idx: y[idx].mean(), transform=True)) # [1.  1.  1.  5.  4.5 4.5 6.  5. ]
print(group_by(x, lambda idx: [y[idx].min(), y[idx].max()]).T) # [[0 3 6 4] [2 7 6 5]]
print(group_by(x, lambda idx: y[idx])) # [[0, 1, 2], [3, 7], [6], [4, 5]]
````

More usage examples here: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77151441/3671939) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77151604/3671939).