# numpy group by index

Tags: python, numpy

```
a = np.array([[1.2, 1.4, 2.2], [2.1, 1.2, 0.5],[1.1, 1.5, 2.3]])

group_id= np.array([0,1,0])
```

The group id define which group the array belongs to, for each group, the mean of the array is calculated.

The expected result should be:

```
[[1.15,1.45,2.25], [2.1,1.2,0.5]]
```

How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: `groupby` operations are best done with pandas. `import pandas as pd;  result = pd.DataFrame(a).groupby(group_id).mean().values`

Comment: Can this done by using just numpy?

Comment: Maybe, but would not be as simple or as fast as pandas.

Answer (score 2):

Use [1-hot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) encoding to vectorize your code.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1.2, 1.4, 2.2], [2.1, 1.2, 0.5],[1.1, 1.5, 2.3]])
group_id= np.array([0,1,0])

def onehot(arr):
    ''' Returns a 1-hot encoding array of arr
    With no zero groups, returns sorted labels
    '''
    arr_local=np.copy(arr)
    unique_arr=np.unique(arr_local)
    one_hot=(arr_local.reshape(-1,1)==unique_arr.reshape(1,-1)).astype(np.int)
    return one_hot,unique_arr

one_hot,_=onehot(group_id)
one_hot.T@a/one_hot.sum(axis=0).reshape(-1,1)
```

Comment: Wow! Very neat! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example. Please forgive that I'm not sure how efficient this code is.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1.2, 1.4, 2.2], [2.1, 1.2, 0.5],[1.1, 1.5, 2.3]])

group_id= np.array([0,1,0])
unique_id = np.unique(group_id)

# prepare a variable
num_elements = a.shape[1]
num_id = len(unique_id)
results = np.zeros((num_id, num_elements))

# iterate over a set of unique id
for id, result in zip(unique_id, results):
    rows = np.where(group_id == id)
    result += a[rows].mean(axis=0)

print(results)
```

Thie yields:

```
[[1.15 1.45 2.25]
 [2.1  1.2  0.5 ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this group_by](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77150915/3671939) function that I wrote for a similar question as follows:

```py
a = np.array([[1.2, 1.4, 2.2], [2.1, 1.2, 0.5], [1.1, 1.5, 2.3]])
group_id = np.array([0, 1, 0])

print(group_by(group_id, lambda idx: a[idx].mean(axis=0))[2])
# [[1.15 1.45 2.25] [2.1  1.2  0.5 ]]
```

Basically, the lambda is called first with `idx=[0, 2]` and then with `idx=[1]`, because the group ids are `[0 1 0]`, and then the results are stacked together.

I recommend this function because it's very flexible: I used it also for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77151441/3671939) and [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77151604/3671939) questions that required group-by, apply or transform in numpy.