# Numpy group by multiple vectors, get group indices

Tags: python, numpy

I have several numpy arrays; I want to build a groupby method that would have group ids for these arrays. It will then allow me to index these arrays on the group id to perform operations on the groups.

For an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,3])
b = np.array([1,2,2,2,3,3])

def group_np(groupcols):
    groupby = np.array([''.join([str(b) for b in bs]) for bs in zip(*[c for c in groupcols])])
    _, groupby = np.unique(groupby, return_invesrse=True)
   return groupby

def group_pd(groupcols):
    df = pd.DataFrame(groupcols[0])
    for i in range(1, len(groupcols)):
        df[i] = groupcols[i]
    for i in range(len(groupcols)):
        df[i] = df[i].fillna(-1)
    return df.groupby(list(range(len(groupcols)))).grouper.group_info[0]
```

Outputs:

```
group_np([a,b]) -> [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
group_pd([a,b]) -> [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Is there a more efficient way of implementing it, ideally in pure numpy? The bottleneck currently seems to be building a vector that would have unique values for each group - at the moment I am doing that by concatenating the values for each vector as strings.

I want this to work for any number of input vectors, which can have millions of elements.

Edit: here is another testcase:

```
a = np.array([1,2,1,1,1,2,3,1])
b = np.array([1,2,2,2,2,3,3,2])
```

Here, group elements 2,3,4,7 should all be the same.

Edit2: adding some benchmarks.

```
a = np.random.randint(1, 1000, 30000000)
b = np.random.randint(1, 1000, 30000000)
c = np.random.randint(1, 1000, 30000000)

def group_np2(groupcols):
    _, groupby = np.unique(np.stack(groupcols), return_inverse=True, axis=1)
    return groupby

%timeit group_np2([a,b,c])
# 25.1 s +/- 1.06 s per loop (mean +/- std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit group_pd([a,b,c])
# 21.7 s +/- 646 ms per loop (mean +/- std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using `np.stack` on the arrays `a` and `b`, if you set the parameter `return_inverse` to `True` in [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) then it is the output you are looking for:

```
a = np.array([1,2,1,1,1,2,3,1])
b = np.array([1,2,2,2,2,3,3,2])
_, inv = np.unique(np.stack([a,b]), axis=1, return_inverse=True)
print (inv)

array([0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1], dtype=int64)
```

and you can replace `[a,b]` in `np.stack` by a list of all the vectors.

**Edit**: a faster solution is use `np.unique` on the `sum` of the arrays multiply by the cumulative product (`np.cumprod`) of the `max` plus 1 of all previous arrays in `groupcols`. such as:

```
def group_np_sum(groupcols):
    groupcols_max = np.cumprod([ar.max()+1 for ar in groupcols[:-1]])
    return np.unique( sum([groupcols[0]] +
                          [ ar*m for ar, m in zip(groupcols[1:],groupcols_max)]), 
                      return_inverse=True)[1]
```

To check:

```
a = np.array([1,2,1,1,1,2,3,1])
b = np.array([1,2,2,2,2,3,3,2])
print (group_np_sum([a,b]))
array([0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Note: the number associated to each group may not be the same (here I changed the first element of `a` by 3)

```
a = np.array([3,2,1,1,1,2,3,1])
b = np.array([1,2,2,2,2,3,3,2])
print(group_np2([a,b]))
print (group_np_sum([a,b]))
array([3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0], dtype=int64)
array([0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1], dtype=int64)
```

but groups themselves are the same.

Now to check for timing:

```
a = np.random.randint(1, 100, 30000)
b = np.random.randint(1, 100, 30000)
c = np.random.randint(1, 100, 30000)
groupcols = [a,b,c]

%timeit group_pd(groupcols)
#13.7 ms ± 1.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit group_np2(groupcols)
#34.2 ms ± 6.88 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit group_np_sum(groupcols)
#3.63 ms ± 562 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have added some benchmarks to the original post and it seems like this method is still 7 times slower than the pandas implementation.

Comment: @rinspy just a question, when you used your function `group_pd` with 3 arrays a, b, and c, did you change in the `groupby` the columns such as `groupby([0, 1, 2])` instead of `groupby([0, 1])` or you want only the group on the first two arrays?

Comment: @rinspy then you'll see with `pandas` it is definitely slower... ;) I would suggest to try with only 3000 in your arrays a, b, c or it will be really long

Comment: See my update - they seem roughly the same. Numpy slightly slower but not meaningfully so. Interestingly, with length 3000 numpy is in fact ~4 times faster.

Comment: @rinspy indeed interesting. I'll have a look at this. By the way, if you want to improve your method with `pandas`, you can create the dataframe with `df = pd.DataFrame({i:ar for i, ar in enumerate(groupcols)}).fillna(-1)` it will be slightly faster :)

Comment: @rinspy I added a faster solution if you want to have a look

Comment: This numpy solution does not work on 'object' dtypes... It seems that the pandas solution is more robust.

Answer (score 1):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (dsiclaimer: I am its authos) covers these type of use cases:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
npi.group_by((a, b))
```

Passing a tuple of index-arrays like this avoids creating a copy; but if you dont mind making the copy you can use stacking as well:

```
npi.group_by(np.stack(a, b))
```

Comment: Thank you - I am not able to try it at the moment, but it would be interesting to benchmark it against the pandas implementation - see my latest edit.

Comment: It will be similar to the numpy implementation in terms of performance characteristics. The implementation is pure-numpy; the reason i made this package was to wrap up those operations in a clean interface.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a `group_by` function ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77150915/3671939)) for another question. The function is very flexible and can solve the problem you request:

```py
from itertools import count

# First test case:
a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3])
b = np.array([1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3])
data = np.stack([a, b], axis=-1)
ids = count()
print(group_by(data, lambda _: next(ids), transform=True)) # [0 1 1 2 3 4]

# Second test case:
a = np.array([1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1])
b = np.array([1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2])
data = np.stack([a, b], axis=-1)
ids = count()
second = group_by(data, lambda _: next(ids), transform=True)
print(second, second[[2, 3, 4, 7]]) # [0 2 1 1 1 3 4 1] [1 1 1 1]
```

I want to point out that the accepted answer is not answering your question of enumerating the groups. It is computing the inverse indices. But it does highlight the parameter `axis` of `np.unique`, which is the most crucial point.