# Convert numpy rows into columns based on ID

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

Suppose I have a `numpy` array that maps between IDs of two item types:

```
[[1, 12],
 [1, 13],
 [1, 14],
 [2, 13],
 [2, 14],
 [3, 11]]
```

I would like to rearrange this array such that each row in the new array represents all items that matched the same ID in the original array. Here, each column would represent one of the mappings in the original array, up to a specified shape restriction on the number of columns in the new array. If we wanted to obtain this result from the above array, ensuring we only had 2 columns, we would obtain:

```
[[12, 13],  #Represents 1 - 14 was not kept as only 2 columns are allowed
 [13, 14],  #Represents 2
 [11,  0]]  #Represents 3 - 0 was used as padding since 3 did not have 2 mappings
```

The naïve approach here would be to use a for-loop that populates the new array as it encounters rows in the original array. Is there a more efficient means of accomplishing this with `numpy`'s functionality?

Comment: Very similar question to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013778/is-there-any-numpy-group-by-function but not an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach using a sparse matrix:

```
def pp(map_, maxitems=2):
    M = sparse.csr_matrix((map_[:, 1], map_[:, 0], np.arange(map_.shape[0]+1)))
    M = M.tocsc()
    sizes = np.diff(M.indptr)
    ids, = np.where(sizes)
    D = np.concatenate([M.data, np.zeros((maxitems - 1,), dtype=M.data.dtype)])
    D = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(D, (D.size - maxitems + 1, maxitems),
                                        2 * D.strides)
    result = D[M.indptr[ids]]
    result[np.arange(maxitems) >= sizes[ids, None]] = 0
    return result
```

Timings using @crisz's code but modified to use less repetitive test data. Also I added a bit of "validation": chrisz's and my solutions give the same answer, the other two output a different format, so I couldn't check them.

[image]

Code:

```
from scipy import sparse
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict, deque

def pp(map_, maxitems=2):
    M = sparse.csr_matrix((map_[:, 1], map_[:, 0], np.arange(map_.shape[0]+1)))
    M = M.tocsc()
    sizes = np.diff(M.indptr)
    ids, = np.where(sizes)
    D = np.concatenate([M.data, np.zeros((maxitems - 1,), dtype=M.data.dtype)])
    D = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(D, (D.size - maxitems + 1, maxitems),
                                        2 * D.strides)
    result = D[M.indptr[ids]]
    result[np.arange(maxitems) >= sizes[ids, None]] = 0
    return result

def chrisz(a):
  return [[*a[a[:,0]==i,1],0][:2] for i in np.unique(a[:,0])]

def piotr(a):
  d = defaultdict(lambda: deque((0, 0), maxlen=2))
  for key, val in a:
    d[key].append(val)
  return d

def karams(arr):
  cols = arr.shape[1]
  ids = arr[:, 0]
  inds = np.where(np.diff(ids) != 0)[0] + 1
  sp = np.split(arr[:,1:], inds)
  result = [a[:2].ravel() if a.size >= cols else np.pad(a.ravel(), (0, cols -1 * (cols - a.size)), 'constant')for a in sp]
  return result

def make(nid, ntot):
    return np.c_[np.random.randint(0, nid, (ntot,)),
                 np.random.randint(0, 2**30, (ntot,))]

from timeit import timeit
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

res = pd.DataFrame(
       index=['pp', 'chrisz', 'piotr', 'karams'],
       columns=[10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000],# 50000],
       dtype=float
)

for c in res.columns:
#        l = np.repeat(np.array([[1, 12],[1, 13],[1, 14],[2, 13],[2, 14],[3, 11]]), c, axis=0)
    l = make(c // 2, c * 6)
    assert np.all(chrisz(l) == pp(l))
    for f in res.index:
        stmt = '{}(l)'.format(f)
        setp = 'from __main__ import l, {}'.format(f)
        res.at[f, c] = timeit(stmt, setp, number=30)

ax = res.div(res.min()).T.plot(loglog=True)
ax.set_xlabel("N");
ax.set_ylabel("time (relative)");

plt.show()
```

Comment: I had a suspicion that my timings were good on repetitive results since it only really looped three times. Nice approach!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a general and mostly Numpythonic approach:

```
In [144]: def array_packer(arr):
     ...:     cols = arr.shape[1]
     ...:     ids = arr[:, 0]
     ...:     inds = np.where(np.diff(ids) != 0)[0] + 1
     ...:     sp = np.split(arr[:,1:], inds)
     ...:     result = [np.unique(a[: cols]) if a.shape[0] >= cols else
     ...:                    np.pad(np.unique(a), (0, (cols - 1) * (cols - a.shape[0])), 'constant')
     ...:                 for a in sp]
     ...:     return result
     ...:     
     ...:
```

Demo:

```
In [145]: a = np.array([[1, 12, 15, 45],
     ...:  [1, 13, 23, 9],
     ...:  [1, 14, 14, 11],
     ...:  [2, 13, 90, 34],
     ...:  [2, 14, 23, 43],
     ...:  [3, 11, 123, 53]])
     ...:  

In [146]: array_packer(a)
Out[146]: 
[array([ 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 23, 45,  0,  0,  0]),
 array([13, 14, 23, 34, 43, 90,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]),
 array([ 11,  53, 123,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0])]

In [147]: a = np.array([[1, 12, 15],
     ...:  [1, 13, 23],
     ...:  [1, 14, 14],
     ...:  [2, 13, 90],
     ...:  [2, 14, 23],
     ...:  [3, 11, 123]])
     ...: 
     ...:   
     ...:  

In [148]: array_packer(a)
Out[148]: 
[array([12, 13, 14, 15, 23]),
 array([13, 14, 23, 90,  0,  0]),
 array([ 11, 123,   0,   0,   0,   0])]
```

Answer (score 2):

For this problem the naive for-loop is actually quite an efficient solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict, deque
d = defaultdict(lambda: deque((0, 0), maxlen=2))

%%timeit
for key, val in a:
    d[key].append(val)
4.43 µs ± 29.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

# result: {1: deque([13, 14]), 2: deque([13, 14]), 3: deque([0, 11])}
```

For comparison, a numpy solution proposed in this thread is 4 times slower:

```
%timeit [[*a[a[:,0]==i,1],0][:2] for i in np.unique(a[:,0])]
18.6 µs ± 336 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Numpy is great and I use it a lot myself, but I think it this case it is cumbersome.

Comment: Nice algorithmic vision!

Comment: Regarding your benchmarks please run the benchmarks with large arrays as well. Also note that you need to pad the arrays with zero instead of None. Plus padding should start from right.

Comment: I changed padding from None to 0. Thanks for pointing that out @Kasramvd!

Comment: I just timed this on a list 10000 times as large and the numpy approach was much faster, I'd appreciate someone else to validate the timings so it doesn't seem biased.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly adapted from the almost duplicate to pad and select only two elements:

```
[[*a[a[:,0]==i,1],0][:2] for i in np.unique(a[:,0])]
```

Output:

```
[[12, 13], [13, 14], [11, 0]]
```

If you want to keep track of keys:

```
{i:[*a[a[:,0]==i,1],0][:2] for i in np.unique(a[:,0])}

# {1: [12, 13], 2: [13, 14], 3: [11, 0]}
```

***Functions***

```
def chrisz(a):
  return [[*a[a[:,0]==i,1],0][:2] for i in np.unique(a[:,0])]

def piotr(a):
  d = defaultdict(lambda: deque((0, 0), maxlen=2))
  for key, val in a:
    d[key].append(val)
  return d

def karams(arr):
  cols = arr.shape[1]
  ids = arr[:, 0]
  inds = np.where(np.diff(ids) != 0)[0] + 1
  sp = np.split(arr[:,1:], inds)
  result = [a[:2].ravel() if a.size >= cols else np.pad(a.ravel(), (0, cols -1 * (cols - a.size)), 'constant')for a in sp]
  return result
```

***Timings***

```
from timeit import timeit
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

res = pd.DataFrame(
       index=['chrisz', 'piotr', 'karams'],
       columns=[10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000],
       dtype=float
)

for f in res.index:
    for c i

n res.columns:
        l = np.repeat(np.array([[1, 12],[1, 13],[1, 14],[2, 13],[2, 14],[3, 11]]), c, axis=0)
        stmt = '{}(l)'.format(f)
        setp = 'from __main__ import l, {}'.format(f)
        res.at[f, c] = timeit(stmt, setp, number=30)

ax = res.div(res.min()).T.plot(loglog=True)
ax.set_xlabel("N");
ax.set_ylabel("time (relative)");

plt.show()
```

***Results*** (Clearly @Kasramvd is the winner):

[image]