# Python: effective way to find the cumulative sum of repeated index (numpy method)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-manipulation, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2d numpy array with repeated values in first column.
The repeated values can have any corresponding value in second column.

Its easy to find the cumsum using numpy, but, I have to find the cumsum for all the repeated values.

How can we do this effectively using numpy or pandas?

Here, I have solved the problem using ineffective for-loop.
I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

**Question** 
How can we get the same result in more effective fashion?

Help will be appreciated.

```
#!python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-#
#
# Imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)  # make results reproducible

aa = np.random.randint(1, 20, size=10).astype(float)
bb = np.arange(10)*0.1

unq = np.unique(aa)

ans = np.zeros(len(unq))
print(aa)
print(bb)
print(unq)

for i, u in enumerate(unq):
    for j, a in enumerate(aa):
        if a == u:
            print(a, u)
            ans[i] += bb[j]

print(ans)


"""
# given data
idx  col0  col1
0    7.    0.0 
1    15.   0.1
2    11.   0.2
3    8.    0.3
4    7.    0.4
5    19.   0.5
6    11.   0.6
7    11.   0.7
8    4.    0.8
9    8.    0.9


# sorted data
4.    0.8
7.    0.0
7.    0.4
8.    0.9
8.    0.3
11.   0.6
11.   0.7
11.   0.2
15.   0.1
19.   0.5

# cumulative sum for repeated serial
4.    0.8
7.    0.0 + 0.4
8.    0.9 + 0.3
11.   0.6 + 0.7 + 0.2
15.   0.1
19.   0.5

# Required answer
4.    0.8 
7.    0.4    
8.    1.2
11.   1.5
15.   0.1
19.   0.5
"""
```

Comment: I think you are looking to do a `groupby()`...

Comment: If `aa` is integer and from a not too large interval you can use `np.bincount(aa, bb, aa.max()+1)` I didn't benchmark it but would expect it too typically to scale better than pandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `groupby` `col0` and find the `.sum()` for `col1`.

```
df.groupby('col0')['col1'].sum()
```

Output:

```
col0
4.0     0.8
7.0     0.4
8.0     1.2
11.0    1.5
15.0    0.1
19.0    0.5
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, can we also do it in numpy ?

Comment: @astro123, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013778/is-there-any-numpy-group-by-function) question talks about numpy approach.

Answer (score 2):

I think a `pandas` method such as the one offered by @HarvIpan is best for readability and functionality, but since you asked for a `numpy` method as well, here is a way to do it in `numpy` using a list comprehension, which is more succinct than your original loop:

```
np.array([[i,np.sum(bb[np.where(aa==i)])] for i in np.unique(aa)])
```

which returns:

```
array([[  4. ,   0.8],
       [  7. ,   0.4],
       [  8. ,   1.2],
       [ 11. ,   1.5],
       [ 15. ,   0.1],
       [ 19. ,   0.5]])
```