# How to join each 2 rows with 2 column in one row in python?

Tags: python-3.x, transpose

I am trying to join each 2 rows with 2 columns into one column.

I have a data like that, And it is stored in a text file

```
7.0 1042.3784354104064 1041.8736266399212 0.0
7.0 567.603384919274 566.8152346188947 0.0
8.0 709.5076838990026 709.3588638367074 0.0
8.0 386.811514883702 386.6412338380912 0.0
```

The expected output will be like that

```
1042.3784354104064 1041.8736266399212 567.603384919274 566.8152346188947
709.5076838990026 709.3588638367074 386.811514883702 386.6412338380912
```

Comment: What format is this data in?  Nested lists, a pandas dataframe, ...?

Comment: a regular 2D numpy array

Comment: Your expected output isn't a transpose.  It looks like you want to take all of the rows that share a first column and join their second and third columns into a list?

Comment: Yes, this is what i want. Sorry i think it will be like transposing

Comment: @PatrickHaugh a 2D numpy array loaded from a text file

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary mapping your first column values to lists, and then populate those lists as you iterate through your matrix:

```
from collections import defaultdict

matrix = [[7.0, 1042.3784354104064, 1041.8736266399212, 0.0],
[7.0, 567.603384919274, 566.8152346188947, 0.0],
[8.0, 709.5076838990026, 709.3588638367074, 0.0],
[8.0, 386.811514883702, 386.6412338380912, 0.0]]

dd = defaultdict(list)

for key, *values, discard in matrix:
    dd[key].extend(values)

result = list(dd.values())

print(result)
# [[1042.3784354104064, 1041.8736266399212, 567.603384919274, 566.8152346188947], 
#  [709.5076838990026, 709.3588638367074, 386.811514883702, 386.6412338380912]]
```

Here's a pure numpy solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43094244/6779307)

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.loadtxt('file.txt')

indices = np.cumsum(np.unique(mat[:, 0], return_counts=True)[1])[:-1]

result = np.array(np.split(mat[:, 1:-1], indices)).reshape((len(indices)+1, -1))
print(result)
# [[1042.37843541 1041.87362664  567.60338492  566.81523462]
#  [ 709.5076839   709.35886384  386.81151488  386.64123384]]
```

Comment: it works but my original data are stored in a text file. Another thing is that the output prints the second row as the first one, and the expected first row as the second one

Comment: @HadeerZayat What is your expected order?  First appearance of the key in the file, sorted by key, the data in the file is already grouped?

Comment: when i tried your code it gives me the following output ""[709.5076838990026, 709.3588638367074, 386.811514883702, 386.6412338380912]]"" 
then it prints ""[1042.3784354104064, 1041.8736266399212, 567.603384919274, 566.8152346188947]""

i need it to be 
# [[1042.3784354104064, 1041.8736266399212, 567.603384919274, 566.8152346188947], 
#  [709.5076838990026, 709.3588638367074, 386.811514883702, 386.6412338380912]]

Comment: @HadeerZayat I've added a pure numpy solution that should also preserve order.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will transpose a list of lists, which I believe is what you're asking for.  You can trim this `new_data` if you are looking to remove some rows.

```
raw_data = [[7.0, 1042.3784354104064, 1041.8736266399212, 0.0],
[7.0, 567.603384919274, 566.8152346188947, 0.0],
[8.0, 709.5076838990026, 709.3588638367074, 0.0],
[8.0, 386.811514883702, 386.6412338380912, 0.0]]

new_data = []
for i, data in enumerate(raw_data):
    for j, d in enumerate(data): 
        if(i==0):
            new_data.append([])
        new_data[j].append(d)

print(new_data)
```