# Python - How to split an array based on the first column?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split, reshape

I have below fake data. After reading it into array it will have shape (8, 3). Now I want to split the data based on the first column(ID) and return a list of array whose shape will be:[(3,3),(2,3),(3,3)]. I think np.split could do the job by assigning a 1-D array to "indices_or_sections" argument. But is there any more convenient way to do this?

```
1   700 35
1   700 35
1   700 35
2   680 25
2   680 25
3   750 40
3   750 40
3   750 40
```

Comment: are you open to non numpy solutions?

Comment: If values in the 1st column are continuous?

Comment: `np.split(a,np.flatnonzero(np.diff(a[:,0]))+1)` is about as convenient as it gets.

Comment: This may be a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013778/is-there-any-numpy-group-by-function

Comment: NumPy arrays usually contain data that is all of the same type, and all measuring the same thing. It looks a lot like [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) will help you, as its explicitly designed for handling columnar data like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any numpy group by function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013778/is-there-any-numpy-group-by-function)

Comment: Yes https://stackoverflow.com/a/53859634/7554103 in the post should work. Thanks, CoryNezin  kwinkunks

Comment: @JacobIRR I guess pandas could also work but I am going to work on large scale data so probably numpy would be faster?

Comment: @kwinkunks I guess pandas could also work but I am going to work on large scale data so probably numpy would be faster?

Comment: @BAKEZQ no they could be any random numbers.

Comment: @PaulPanzer yes, I think you are correct.

Comment: @CarlosWen Doubtful: Pandas uses NumPy arrays to represent its data. If you need more horsepower (e.g. have huge dataframes), there's [`dask`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) or [`vaex`](https://github.com/vaexio/vaex), both of which work out-of-core (i.e. the dataframe doesn't have to fit in memory).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a combination of `np.split`, `sort`, `np.unique` and `np.cumsum`.

```py
>>> a = [[1, 700, 35],
...      [1, 700, 35],
...      [1, 700, 35],
...      [2, 680, 25],
...      [2, 680, 25],
...      [3, 750, 40],
...      [3, 750, 40],
...      [3, 750, 40]]
>>> a = np.array(a)
>>> # sort the array by first column. 
>>> a = a[a[:,0].argsort()]
>>> np.split(a, np.cumsum(np.unique(a[:, 0], return_counts=True)[1])[:-1])
[array([[  1, 700,  35],
       [  1, 700,  35],
       [  1, 700,  35]]), array([[  2, 680,  25],
       [  2, 680,  25]]), array([[  3, 750,  40],
       [  3, 750,  40],
       [  3, 750,  40]])]
```