# How to sum an ND array in python based on like entries?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have an ND array in python represented by the following scheme:

```
["Event ID", "Event Location", "Event Cost"]
data = \
[[1, 0, 500]
[1, 0, 250]
[1, 1, 300]
[2, 0, 750]
[2, 1, 400]
[2, 1, 500]]
```

How can I collapse this array to sum up the cost for entries with the same event ID that happened in the same event location? This would give me the following array at the end:

```
[[1, 0, 750]
[1, 1, 300]
[2, 0, 750]
[2, 1, 900]]
```

Comment: Have you considered using pandas and groupby?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any numpy group by function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013778/is-there-any-numpy-group-by-function)

Comment: @MadPhysicist answered my question. Pandas worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Pandas and the following line to solve this:

```
dg = data.groupby(['Event ID', 'Event Location'])['Event Cost'].sum().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic use-case for [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
import itertools

result = [
    [i, loc, sum(cost for _, _, cost in costs)]
    for (i, loc), costs in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda t: (t[0], t[1]))
]
```

Comment: Is it still a classic use case if you're grouping over a numpy array (I don't think so...).

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't work, just that it's not very performant.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer two ways to do it:

#### Using `numpy_indexed` package:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy_indexed as npi
a = np.array([[1, 0, 500],[1, 0, 250],[1, 1, 300],[2, 0, 750],[2, 1, 400],[2, 1, 500]])
_, sums = npi.group_by(a[:,:2]).sum(a[:,2])
result = np.hstack([_, np.vstack(sums)])
print(result)
```

Output:

```
_ = 
[[1 0], 
[1 1], 
[2 0], 
[2 1]]
sums = [750, 300, 750, 900]
np.vstack(sums) = 
[[750]
 [300]
 [750]
 [900]]
result = 
[[  1   0 750]
 [  1   1 300]
 [  2   0 750]
 [  2   1 900]]
```

#### Using `pandas`:

```
df.groupby([0,1]).sum().reset_index().values
```