# Merge sum two numpy arrays, one as key, another as value

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Is there any function to do a groupby sum on numpy array?

maybe duplicated with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013778/is-there-any-numpy-group-by-function)

```py
x = np.array([[1.2, 10],
              [2.3, 20],
              [1.2, 30],
              [2.3, 7]
            ])
```

wanted output:

```py
x = np.array([[1.2, 40],
              [2.3, 27]            
            ])
```

Update:

Actually, the first column of my data is always rounded to two decimals. So `x` can be written as:

```py
x = np.array([[120, 10],
              [230, 20],
              [120, 30],
              [230, 7]
            ])
```

Comment: What is that you have tried ?

Comment: Be aware that values coming from real data are very rarely equal to each other, so it's actually extremely unlikely for you to have duplicate floating-point keys. Depending on what this is for, you may want to use something more like a histogram instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say this is duplicate but related question you mentioned is a good point to start with. A majority of answers of your link requires to sort array, extract indices where groups begin and then call `np.split` on it. That's not a case here because it would return a list of groups that are not balanced in size.

Instead you can use `np.bincount` method. It counts number of occurrences of each weighted value and this is actually the same as groupby sum, only group keys are absent from output.

```
def group_by_sum(x):
    u, idx = np.unique(x[:,0], return_inverse=True)
    s = np.bincount(idx, weights = x[:,1])
    return np.c_[u, s]
```

***Bonus.*** It's actually a oneliner in `numpy_indexed` package:

```
np.transpose(npi.group_by(x[:, 0]).sum(x[:, 1]))
```

#### Benchmarking

```
import numpy as np
import perfplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def bincount(x):
    u, idx = np.unique(x[:,0], return_inverse=True)
    s = np.bincount(idx, weights = x[:,1])
    return np.c_[u, s]

def reduceat(x):
    x = x[np.argsort(x[:, 0])]
    i = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(x[:, 0]))
    i = np.r_[0, i + 1]
    s = np.add.reduceat(x[:, 1], i)
    return np.stack((x[i, 0], s), axis=-1)

def setup(N, s):
    x = np.linspace(0,1,N+1)[np.random.randint(N, size = s)]
    return np.c_[x, (x**2)%1]

def build_args(k):
    return {'setup': lambda x: setup(k, x),
            'kernels': [bincount, reduceat],
            'n_range': [2**k for k in range(1, 20)],
            'title': f'Testing for x samples in [0, 1] with no more than {k} groups',
            'show_progress': True,
            'equality_check': False}

outs = [perfplot.bench(**build_args(n)) for n in (10, 100, 1000, 10000)]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
for i in range(len(outs)):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, i + 1)
    ax.grid(True, which="both")
    outs[i].plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. Don't know how this method works internally though but `np.add.reduceat` is a nice feature too.

Comment: `unique` works internally by sorting, so both methods have the same complexity. Do you have the resources to benchmark them against each other?

Comment: @Mad Physicist. Good catch. It's interesting for me too but I'm busy with another problem at the moment so I'll benchmark it in forthcoming day and update an answer.

Comment: They are pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using unique values to count repetitions for each element and multiply it by its value to calculate the groupby sum (You can achieve it faster by implementing a hashmap of `O(n)` that only counts the repetitions and unique values):

**EDIT since original question is edited:**

```
keys2, idx, count = np.unique(x[:,0], return_counts=True, return_index=True)
values2 = x[:,1][idx]*count
```

Another way is using pandas groupby:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'keys':x[:,0], 'values':x[:,1]})
df2 = df.groupby(keys)['values'].agg('sum')
keys2, values2 = df2.index.to_numpy(), df2.values
```

output:

```
[1.2 2.3] 
[20 30]
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist You mean `return_index`? that makes sense. Thank you. Edited the post.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I see. Thank you for correcting me. For this specific example, however, we can still accomplish the task with a hashmap with `O(n)` without the need to know which elements are the same. Only counts and the values are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy provides the tools to do this without explicit looping.

First sort the rows:

```
a = a[np.argsort(a[:, 0])]
```

Then find the indices where the value changes:

```
i = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(a[:, 0]))
i = np.r_[0, i + 1]
```

Then add up the elements:

```
s = np.add.reduceat(a[:, 1], i)
```

The index is just the first element of `a` in each run, so the result is

```
result = np.stack((a[i, 0], s), axis=-1)
```

Comment: Is sorting necessary for this problem? I think it is costlier than it needs to be.

Comment: @Ehsan. Yes. That's how `unique` works internally. Otherwise you won't know which elements are the same. It's more complex than a hash table, but I suspect that it's faster than a python `set` for most practically-sized applications.

Comment: Thank you. Is it necessary to know which elements are the same? Isn't count and the unique values enough (like I used in my post)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method

```
d = {}
for k,v in x:
    d[k] = d.get(k,0) + v

x = np.array(list(d.items()))
```

keep in mind that this is testing for float equality... something you probably shouldn't do