# How can I speed groupby?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
array = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3], 'A': [False, False, True, False, False, False, True, True],
         'B': [False, True, True, False, True, False, False, False]}
df = pd.DataFrame(array)
df
```

I want to represent each id in one line. If all values of this id on a specific column are False, then its value should be False. If at least one is True - then it should be True.
I have started with:

```
df.groupby(['id']).sum()
```

After which I will convert every value above 0 to 1.
This works fine, but my original dataframe has 2,000,000 rows and 14,000 columns and therefore it takes days....

Any other quicker idea to do the task?

Comment: I would expect `df.groupby(['id']).any()` to work _much_ faster because `any()` is supposed to be short-circuited. Surprisingly, it is actually slower.

Comment: @jezrael - Any ideas? Would value your help here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the second step by taking the maximum instead of the sum over each group:

```py
df.groupby(['id']).max()
```

You might expect that it should be faster to aggregate with `any`, because then each sub-series would only have to be evaluated until the first `True` is reached, but apparently the following is much slower (as per DYZ's comment):

```py
df.groupby(['id']).agg(any)
```

So I would recommend testing it with NumPy's `any` function, which might handle this better:

```
import numpy as np
df.groupby(['id']).agg(np.any)
```

Or you could do without `agg`, as suggested by Henry Ecker:

```
df.groupby(['id']).any()
```

However, none of these methods is as fast as one might expect. So maybe your best bet is to convert the dataframe to a NumPy integer array and do the grouping in pure NumPy. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013778/is-there-any-numpy-group-by-function/43094244).

Comment: It is actually _much_ slower with `any()`. I suspect that pandas' `any()` is not short-circuited.

Comment: Thanks. However, I am not worried about the second step - cause I am still stuck with the first one... :-(

Comment: Thanks @DYZ, I was indeed assuming that it should be short circuited.

Comment: @HenryEcker Even `df.groupby(['id']).any()` is slower than  `df.groupby(['id']).sum()` .

Comment: Yeah I was running timing myself. That's very odd indeed.