# Is function any() in pandas.groupby short-circuited?

Tags: python, pandas, any, short-circuiting

While trying to answer [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68423940/how-can-i-speed-groupby/68424108), I noticed that function `any()`, when applied within `groupby()`, performs equally slow regardless of the content of the dataframe. For example, it takes the same time to inspect a column of `True`s and a column of `False`s. The same is true of `all()`. This observation contradicts the assumption that `any()` is short-circuited.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.random.randint(0, 2, 1000000), 'data': True})
timeit('df.groupby("id").any()', globals=globals(), number=100)
# 1.0371657210052945

df['data'] = False
timeit('df.groupby("id").any()', globals=globals(), number=100)
# 1.0135124520165846
```

Could anyone clarify if the two mentioned functions are short-circuited in Pandas?

Comment: `df.groupby("id").agg(np.any)` gives me identical timing to above. So it might be a question about `np.any` as well.

Comment: Perhaps duplicate of [Why “numpy.any” has no short-circuit mechanism?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45771554/15497888) If it is, that explains why `groupby.max` is so fast in the previous question as well...