# Efficient multinomial sampling for sparse array/tensor in python

Tags: python, pytorch, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse array/tensor like below.

```
import torch
from torch_sparse import SparseTensor


row = torch.tensor([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])
col = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 4, 5, 0, 2, 5, 2, 4])
value = torch.rand([14])
adj_t = SparseTensor(row=row, col=col, value=value, sparse_sizes=(4, 9))
```

I want to sample `n_samples` column index's with or without replacement. I can do this by first converting `adj_t` to `dense` and then using `torch.multinomial` or similarly with `numpy.random.choice`.

```
sample = torch.multinomial(adj_t.to_dense(), num_samples=2, replacement=True)
```

But converting the sparse array to dense and the `torch.multinomial`  is not very efficient. Is there a sparse version of `torch.multinomial`. If no, how would one go about implementing it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this can be done as efficiently as your one-liner.

From what I understand one way to achieve what you want is to:

1. Group values by row in which they appear in sparese tensor e.g. using  [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43094244/7195666): `np.split(value.numpy(), np.unique(row.numpy(), return_index=True)[1][1:])`
2. Use [numpy.random.multinominal](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.multinomial.html) to create the list of randomly chosen indexes for every row
3. map the indexes to respective values from `col` (i.e. `0` in 0th row is `1`, `1` is 1st row is `2`, `2` in 2nd row is `4` - all according to `row` and `col` values)

You might not want to use any built-in loop in order for performence not to drop.