# Python: How to split a list into ordered chunks

Tags: python, numpy

If I have the following list

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Then

```
np.array_split([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 3)
```

Returns

```
[array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6]), array([7, 8, 9])]
```

Is there a way to get the sub-arrays in the following order?

```
[array([0, 3, 6, 9]), array([1, 4, 7]), array([2, 5, 8])]
```

Comment: Is a `numpy.ndarray` required, or will a `list` meet your requirement?

Comment: I need to get a list of sublists (chunks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the lists are of differing lengths, a `numpy.ndarray` isn't possible without a bit of fiddling, as all sub-arrays must be the same length.

However, if a simple `list` meets your requirement, you can use:

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
l2 = []

for i in range(3):
    l2.append(l[i::3])
```

Output:

```
[[0, 3, 6, 9], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8]]
```

Or more concisely, giving the same output:

```
[l[i::3] for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: This solution also works if *l* is a `np.array`. There is no need to convert to `list` first. The result is a `list` of sub-`np.ndarray.view`s (later changes to *l* are reflected in the sub-views).

Answer (score 1):

Let's look into source code refactor of `np.array_split`:

```
def array_split(arr, Nsections):
    Neach_section, extras = divmod(len(arr), Nsections)
    section_sizes = ([0] + extras * [Neach_section + 1] + (Nsections - extras) * [Neach_section])
    div_points = np.array(section_sizes).cumsum()

    sub_arrs = []
    for i in range(Nsections):
        st = div_points[i]
        end = div_points[i + 1]
        sub_arrs.append(arr[st:end])

    return sub_arrs
```

Taking into account your example `arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` and `Nsections = 3` it will construct section sizes `[0, 4, 3, 3]` and dividing points `[0, 4, 7, 10]`. Then do something like this:

```
[arr[div_points[i]:div_points[i + 1]] for i in range(3)]
```

Trying to mimic behaviour of `numpy`, indeed,

```
def array_split_withswap(arr, N):
    sub_arrs = []
    for i in range(N):
        sub_arrs.append(arr[i::N])
```

Is the best option to go with (like in @S3DEV solution).