# Find groups of Y values for unique X values, numpy structured array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `numpy` structured array:

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = (np.array([32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 39, 21], dtype=np.int64),np.array([449, 451, 452, 453, 454, 463, 340], dtype=np.int64))

arr1_x = arr1[0]
arr1_y = arr1[1]

arr1_struct = np.empty(arr1_x.shape[0], dtype=[('x', int), ('y', int)])

arr1_struct["x"] = arr1_x
arr1_struct["y"] = arr1_y
```

I would need to determine the groups of **y** values that correspond to unique **x** values.

Using the above example, I would need to know that:

- Where **x**=32, **y**=449, 451, 452, 453, 454
- Where **x**=39, **y**=463
- Where **x**=21, **y**=340

I was looking into `np.unique` but that didn't give exactly what I'm after.

Any output format would be fine that provides this information. An example would be

- `x_unique = [32,39,21]`
- `y_unique = [ [449,451,452,453,454] , [463] , [340] ]`

Where the X value at index 0 in the `x_unique` array/list has the Y values at index 0 in the `y_unique` array/list, and so on so forth.

Is there an easy and efficient way to do this in `numpy`?

Comment: You can treat the two fields as separate arrays.  But numpy doesn't provide much help with grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to be using `pandas` and work with a dataframe-like structure.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([*arr1], index=['x', 'y']).T
```

which gives

```
    x    y
0  32  449
1  32  451
2  32  452
3  32  453
4  32  454
5  39  463
6  21  340
```

Then,

```
>>> df.groupby('x')['y'].unique().to_dict()
{21: array([340]), 32: array([449, 451, 452, 453, 454]), 39: array([463])}
```

Without pandas, [you can refer to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013778/is-there-any-numpy-group-by-function) for analogous ways to perform a `groupby` with numpy or pure python.