# Finding the average of the x component of an array of coordinates, based on the y component

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have the following example array of x-y coordinate pairs:

```
A = np.array([[0.33703753, 3.],
              [0.90115394, 5.],
              [0.91172016, 5.],
              [0.93230994, 3.],
              [0.08084283, 3.],
              [0.71531777, 2.],
              [0.07880787, 3.],
              [0.03501083, 4.],
              [0.69253184, 4.],
              [0.62214452, 3.],
              [0.26953094, 1.],
              [0.4617873 , 3.],
              [0.6495549 , 0.],
              [0.84531478, 4.],
              [0.08493308, 5.]])
```

My goal is to reduce this to an array with six rows by taking the average of the x-values for each y-value, like so:

```
array([[0.6495549 , 0.        ],
       [0.26953094, 1.        ],
       [0.71531777, 2.        ],
       [0.41882167, 3.        ],
       [0.52428582, 4.        ],
       [0.63260239, 5.        ]])
```

Currently I am achieving this by converting to a pandas dataframe, performing the calculation, and  converting back to a numpy array:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'x':A[:, 0], 'y':A[:, 1]})
>>> df.groupby('y').mean().reset_index()
     y         x
0  0.0  0.649555
1  1.0  0.269531
2  2.0  0.715318
3  3.0  0.418822
4  4.0  0.524286
5  5.0  0.632602
```

Is there a way to perform this calculation using numpy, without having to resort to the pandas library?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any numpy group by function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013778/is-there-any-numpy-group-by-function)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi unfortunately not, answers to that question produce lists of the x-coordinates but do not maintain the y-coordinates nor perform the mean computation.

Comment: Clever np answers have been suggested. But Is there any benefit in not using Pandas which produces the np array using a readable one-liner?

Comment: @user19077881 If this is the only reason pandas is being imported, then a numpy-only answer can avoid the need for an extra library

Comment: @user19077881 I added some timing comparisons between the pandas and numpy-only methods in [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74853319/843953). Numpy-only wins handily, so there's another reason to use it instead of going through pandas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a completely vectorized solution that only uses numpy methods and no python iteration:

```
sort_indices = np.argsort(A[:, 1])
unique_y, unique_indices, group_count  = np.unique(A[sort_indices, 1], return_index=True, return_counts=True)
```

Once we have the indices and counts of all the unique elements, we can use the [`np.ufunc.reduceat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) method to collect the results of `np.add` for each group, and then divide by their counts to get the mean:

```
group_sum = np.add.reduceat(A[sort_indices, :], unique_indices, axis=0)

group_mean = group_sum / group_count[:, None]
# array([[0.6495549 , 0.        ],
#        [0.26953094, 1.        ],
#        [0.71531777, 2.        ],
#        [0.41882167, 3.        ],
#        [0.52428582, 4.        ],
#        [0.63260239, 5.        ]])
```

---

### Benchmarks:

Comparing this solution with the other answers here (Code at [tio.run](https://tio.run/##jVbfj6M2EH7nr3BZnc6cWJLN3Z6qVJEa9drHvNyqLxFCTjDEWzDUNrlwq/3bt@MfGNjstUVRwPbMNzOfxzNue3Vq@MeXl5ufFp0UiwPjC8rPqLXzwQ26/XCLjk3OeLlGnSpuf9YzQRiGwW@CEkVz1HD00FH0hR4R@ozuluv7T@uP92i1XK2C4FfSAZJYo/bUSMJLoxkUoqlR0fGjappKIla3jVCoJUIxUgVuqFhNmRpGvKvbHhGJeBt4eZ7DBPza3ELWRLVVoyp28Ji9njAylQqCnBYGN9PGJTb/MZLsO4UXEWVWUh6j3Wa1jNYBgkcLS7QBq8l3KhqJcUU5NgpRjPS3wYiiyIiXOTsqEC@r5kAqiaPk2LQ9totFIxADa4hxRCEeKoA/h2Wt6Qe80AadM1hGfqUVjCus18c5jfkYo2KOaX0aMb1rSdfmWqBqjsa9aCaiRD/X8Qzswe/HFNyym5LYFw4L/MH4E8ZDyBtjJ9b7daBis4vQAu2uQG0oRfjEnhdPI6PPMXp6dDM2Bj0z8eA5nHtML0faKvQnqTr6uxBABuw0vax/YHDO3fAEVwNBVSe4Dd0mjc6izIyx@Y/RlOOClZA@F@AHsiyR3UGLy8m2//cWkUuilbDLRRvzWscMaUYOtNoUSZZxArmbWdzxD3QlVdnFyOFwKwTpTVI7ttx679YfABu1VNgTyOD8QjJUCFJtLn@RME9xWDXlK6C3FioK6ZpjPy4FG0ZAD2RMeVJZRfqmU27asezIszwPac8z0XwDHnh2hAqh36VoB770pz2TREBNoU46Qu@c3EjNGVLSioJk3tTuhV8ZuL2LZj7tQeEkFTn@hbGGiI1NvR@7htM0ilJr4ubdO@N2kbUATM5461yUUHwyxuEsUO9qqSfxVqPcpdZcx9nfHc16jd907aAxDI9NxxWy@lYU1KfQGil2Tus5etk8iI76KQMgzZwrUAZXdrVzKs8TQfPuCKX8CnqdXrlFLkxullOomhKuC57HXUx994xNyR0Vgxl5GVNUeAa3mSZuu3d8ef4i7diUPFrRGlxzoxnnA2eZtCBvUBXZPJFtxaYbNkfb361TdAORIE6h46nGyiMCXepEIYOFVMhgBiM1zgcjqV2I50YsiZqF6/5i9SNHv9wv00SeSEv3kDezXgJZOS8rTnOsK8aALp7r1GxTm@gZPGzkdF@M6LAlj4TVnd@MIU8hiDcJvqL3TIWkk7wTVHaVskq0blWPscd0sS1BfxVNapuLsZ9H6NUmQVp0HeUytTZMkNu9d3aDzGL0hsqdVulnTNjFgYqccDYe7K52scNdyeQ49hkqVd9CMWoT6DWfP8H2faO66smNkRisn3WzAiLt2fxXHq@OrxiIP7viZNxZOKzYYUdR8vAqHH/SzJ3JR5MXumflyReiyB8CmgveaseqruZysw8v0NfDPkxntTEvEpNlhx6/799HluoIyohuDeYQwEg1mbmxuVIf6EqJvlKFuhY6Ux2YNge29/cQ8DJG90v9Nh/2y36a7wzeaWAaptYYykU8LxzxkLSx27LYh5s686zWyEgXfnQBrkQP11p3xgLTcTPuessPL4kVqQ85cX1m7ftVTS7@Vrjy7SoKpjeD@Q3CmhruEcG8h8PNaER8Nh7/gnbOVei5k3CWQ7UZI9LiQzymOv6vgLTW@qoBr@xu2FBWOpbVm8G4KuyjWc3D2bkYasbxzkGO4by8/AM)) for

1. `A` contains 10k rows, with `A[:, 1]` containing N groups, N varies from 1 to 10k
   [image: Timing for different methods with 10k rows, N groups]
2. `A` contains N rows (N varies from 1 to 10k), with `A[:, 1]` containing `min(N, 1000)` groups
   [image: Timing for different methods with N rows, 1k groups]

**Observations:**
The numpy-only solutions ([Dani's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74853372/843953) and mine) win easily -- they are significantly faster than the pandas approach (possibly since the time taken to create the dataframe is an overhead that doesn't exist for the former).

The pandas solution is *slower* than the python+numpy solutions ([Jaimu's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74853057/843953) and mine) for smaller arrays, since it's faster to just iterate in python and get it over with than to create a dataframe first, but these solutions become much slower than pandas as the array size or number of groups increases.

---

**Note:** The previous version of this answer iterated over the groups as returned by the accepted answer to [Is there any numpy group by function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013778/is-there-any-numpy-group-by-function) and individually calculated the mean:

First, we need to sort the array on the column you want to group by

```
A_s = A[A[:, 1].argsort(), :]
```

Then, run that snippet. `np.split` splits its first argument at the indices given by the second argument.

```
unique_elems, unique_indices = np.unique(A_s[:, 1], return_index=True) 
# (array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.]), array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  9, 12])) 

split_indices = unique_indices[1:] # No need to split at the first index

groups = np.split(A_s, split_indices)
# [array([[0.6495549, 0.       ]]),
#  array([[0.26953094, 1.        ]]),
#  array([[0.71531777, 2.        ]]),
#  array([[0.33703753, 3.        ],
#         [0.93230994, 3.        ],
#         [0.08084283, 3.        ],
#         [0.07880787, 3.        ],
#         [0.62214452, 3.        ],
#         [0.4617873 , 3.        ]]),
#  array([[0.03501083, 4.        ],
#         [0.69253184, 4.        ],
#         [0.84531478, 4.        ]]),
#  array([[0.90115394, 5.        ],
#         [0.91172016, 5.        ],
#         [0.08493308, 5.        ]])]
```

Now, `groups` is a list containing multiple `np.array`s. Iterate over the list and `mean` each array:

```
means = np.zeros((len(groups), groups[0].shape[1]))
for i, grp in enumerate(groups):
    means[i, :] = grp.mean(axis=0)

# array([[0.6495549 , 0.        ],
#        [0.26953094, 1.        ],
#        [0.71531777, 2.        ],
#        [0.41882167, 3.        ],
#        [0.52428582, 4.        ],
#        [0.63260239, 5.        ]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`np.bincount`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) + [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html#numpy.unique):

```
sums = np.bincount(A[:, 1].astype(np.int64), weights=A[:, 0])
values, counts = np.unique(A[:, 1], return_counts=True)
res = np.vstack((sums / counts, values)).T
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[0.6495549  0.        ]
 [0.26953094 1.        ]
 [0.71531777 2.        ]
 [0.41882167 3.        ]
 [0.52428582 4.        ]
 [0.63260239 5.        ]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a work around using numpy.

```py
unique_ys, indices = np.unique(A[:, 1], return_inverse=True)
result = np.empty((unique_ys.shape[0], 2))

for i, y in enumerate(unique_ys):
    result[i, 0] = np.mean(A[indices == i, 0])
    result[i, 1] = y

print(result)
```

**Alternative:**
To make the code more pythonic, you can use a list comprehension to create the `result` array, instead of using a for loop.

```py
unique_ys, indices = np.unique(A[:, 1], return_inverse=True)
result = np.array([[np.mean(A[indices == i, 0]), y] for i, y in enumerate(unique_ys)])

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[[0.6495549  0.        ]
 [0.26953094 1.        ]
 [0.71531777 2.        ]
 [0.41882167 3.        ]
 [0.52428582 4.        ]
 [0.63260239 5.        ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the y values beforehand, you could try to match the array for each:

for example:

`A[(A[:,1]==1),0]` will give you all the x values where the y value is equal to 1.

So you could go through each value of y, sum the `A[:,1]==y[n]` to get the number of matches, sum the x values that match, divide to make the average, and place in a new array:

```
B=np.zeros([6,2])

for i in range( 6):
    nmatch=sum(A[:,1]==i)
    nsum=sum(A[(A[:,1]==i),0])
    
    B[i,0]=i
    B[i,1]=nsum/nmatch
```

There must be a more pythonic way of doing this ....