# Sum elements before and replace element with sum

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have the numpy array

```py
arr = np.array([[0, 0, 2, 5, 0, 0, 1, 8, 0, 3, 0],
                [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0],
                [8, 5, 3, 9, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

I need the result array like this:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 3]
 [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

What's happened?

We go along the row, if element in row is 0, then we go to the next element , if not 0, then we sum up the elements until 0 is met, once 0 is met, then we replace it with the resulting sum (also replace the initial non-zero numbers with 0

I already know how to do that with loops but it doesn't work well on time for a large number of rows, so I need **time-efficient solution in numpy methods**

Comment: I suggest using `np.frompyfunc` to create a custom ufunc that adds or resets to 0, then use `np.ufunc.accumulate`.

Comment: you forgot to include that you are also replacing the initial non zero numbers with 0

Comment: Added details and attempt, @ScottHunter

Comment: @ScottHunter attempts are not necessary on Stack Overflow, and often make the question **worse**. What *is* necessary is proper *analysis* of the problem - breaking it down into steps and then figuring out which step causes a problem. After all, the goal here is to figure out **how to** do something, **not** to identify a specific problem in a specific attempt. This is not a debugging service.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013778 help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, we want to find the locations where the array has a zero next to a non-zero.

```
rr, cc = np.where((arr[:, 1:] == 0) & (arr[:, :-1] != 0))
```

Now, we can use [`np.add.reduceat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) to add elements. Unfortunately, `reduceat` needs a list of 1-d indices, so we're going to have to play with shapes a little. Calculating the equivalent indices of `rr, cc` in a flattened array is easy:

```
reduce_indices = rr * arr.shape[1] + cc + 1
# array([ 4,  8, 10, 13, 19, 26, 28])
```

We want to reduce from the *start of every row*, so we'll create a `row_starts` to mix in with the indices calculated above:

```
row_starts = np.arange(arr.shape[0]) * arr.shape[1]
# array([ 0, 11, 22])

reduce_indices = np.hstack((row_starts, reduce_indices))
reduce_indices.sort()
# array([ 0,  4,  8, 10, 11, 13, 19, 22, 26, 28])
```

Now, call `np.add.reduceat` on the flattened input array, reducing at `reduce_indices`

```
totals = np.add.reduceat(arr.flatten(), reduce_indices)
# array([ 7,  9,  3,  0,  3, 12,  0, 25,  1,  1])
```

Now we have the totals, we need to assign them to an array of zeros. Note that the `0`th element of `totals` needs to go to the `1`th index of `reduce_indices`, and the last element of `totals` is to be discarded:

```
result_f = np.zeros((arr.size,))
result_f[reduce_indices[1:]] = totals[:-1]
result = result_f.reshape(arr.shape)
```

Now, one last step remains. For cases where the last element in a row is nonzero, `reduceat` would calculate a nonzero value for the first element of the next row, as you mentioned in the comment below. An easy solution is to overwrite these to zero.

```
result[:, 0] = 0
```

which gives the expected result:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  7.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  9.,  0.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 12.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 25.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: Good, but for `arr = np.array([[0, 0, 2, 5, 0, 0, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0], [8, 5, 3, 9, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0]])` **it fails**. 

Perhaps at the end of your solution we should add `result[:, 0] = 0`?

Comment: That is a good point, @qtsar! I had a hunch it would fail when the last element of a row isn't zero but I forgot to test for that case. Your solution is a great easy fix for this issue!

Answer (score 1):

We can solve using 2 for loops. In every row we will define current_sum and if number is zero we assign current_sum to number and reset current_sum; if number is not zero we assign 0 to number and we increment current_sum.

Edit: Sorry first i didn't realize you want an efficient solution. We can use numba to accelerate for loops. it is really simple and powerful.
Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import numba
arr = np.array([[0, 0, 2, 5, 0, 0, 1, 8, 0, 3, 0],
                [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0],
                [8, 5, 3, 9, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def mySum(array):
    for i in range(array.shape[0]):
        current_sum = 0
        for j in range(array.shape[1]):
            if array[i,j] == 0:
                array[i,j] = current_sum
                current_sum = 0
            else:
                current_sum += array[i,j]
                array[i,j] = 0
    return array

print(mySum(arr))
```

function is slow in first run because it understands input and function and creates machine code, but after that it is really fast. I hope it is fast enough for your case.

Comment: As far as possible, you shouldn't use loops for a numpy array. More often than not, you'll find numpy indexing and operations can do the job, and much more efficiently than looping

Comment: Oh my bad. I thought op just need a solution, but he wants a time-efficient solution. Yes for loops are bad, but using libraries like numba could really help sometimes. Also every row can be calculated separately so paralel processing may help.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe longer than in loop... But let me demonstrate with single array:

```
a = np.array([0, 0, 2, 5, 0, 0, 1, 8, 0, 3, 0])
zero_index = np.where(a == 0)[0]
# Split zeros, sum each slice, drop the last one
replace_arr = np.array(list(map(sum, np.split(a, zero_index))))[:-1]
output = np.zeros(11)
# Put sum data into zeros array
np.put_along_axis(output, zero_index, replace_arr, axis=0)
output
```