# Mean value calculation for clustered data using NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have two arrays:

- `x` which contains `m` points;
- `c` which contains `m` cluster ids for each corresponding point from `x`.

I want to calculate the mean value for points which share the same id, i.e. which belong to the same cluster. I know that `c` contains integers from the range `[0, k)` and all the values are present in the `c`.
My current solution looks like the following:

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

k = 3
x = np.random.rand(100, 2)
c = np.random.randint(0, k, size=x.shape[0])
mu = np.zeros((k, 2))

for i in range(k):
    mu[i] = x[c == i].mean(axis=0)
```

While this approach works, I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to calculate the means in NumPy without having to use an explicit for loop?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013778/is-there-any-numpy-group-by-function

You might also consider using a pandas groupby, if you're willing to step outside of numpy.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that relatively efficiently using:

```py
# Number of different IDs
size = np.max(c) + 1
xBins = np.zeros(size)
yBins = np.zeros(size)

# Sum by IDs
np.add.at(xBins, c, x[:,0])
np.add.at(yBins, c, x[:,1])

# Compute the number of item per ID
counts = np.bincount(c)

# Compute the mean
xBins /= counts
yBins /= counts

# Build the final array
mu = np.vstack([xBins, yBins]).T
```

Also note that using a `(2,N)` array is generally more efficient for storing points than using a `(N,2)` array.

Comment: Implementing the example given in the question, this method and the most efficient version from the link that @Chrysophylaxs commented with, Jérôme's is the most efficient.


andywiecko: 0.37ms / 10k iter;
Chrysophylaxs (et al): 0.58;
Jérôme: 0.34 .

Comment: You don't need to separate into `xBins, yBins`. Simply define `bins = np.zeros((size, x.shape[1])` and then `np.add.at(bins, c, x)` gives the sum per bin. This works well when `x` has many columns where it wouldn't be practical to separate each column into a separate variable