# How to groupby numpy ndarray and return first row from each group. Now sort before

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have ndarray:

```
[[1 1]
 [0 2]
 [0 3]
 [1 4]
 [1 5]
 [0 6]
 [1 7]]
```

I expect reduced result like that:

```
[[1 1]
  [0 2]
  [1 4]
  [0 6]
  [1 7]]
```

Result ndarray should contain first row from each group.
I build a groups on values from column 0. This is values 0 or 1.

Similar problem was resolved in thread: [Is there any numpy group by function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38013778/9403794)
But there key was sorted and in my case it does not work.

```
l1 = [1,0,0,1,1,0,1]
l2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
a = np.array([l1, l2]).T
print(a)
values, indexes = np.unique(a[:, 0], return_index=True)
```

In pandas we can achieve this by (solution from stack, but i do not remember owner, sorry for no link):

```
m1 = ( df['c0'] != df['c0'].shift(1)).cumsum()
df = df.groupby([df['c0'], m1]).head(1)
```

How to make it with numpy?

Thank you for solutions.

EDITED:

At the time when mozway wrote solution i created something like that:

```
import numpy as np

l1 = [1,0,0,1,1,0,1]
l2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
a = np.array([l1, l2]).T

print("solution")
"shift for numpy"
arr3 = np.array([np.NaN])
arr4 = np.array(a[ :-1, 0])
arr5 = np.concatenate([arr3, arr4])
print('arr5')
print(arr5)
"add shifted column"
a = np.c_[ a, arr5 ]

"diff between column 0 and shofted colum"
dif_col = np.where(a[:, 0] != a[:, 2], True, False)
"add diff column"
a = np.c_[ a, dif_col ]
"select only true"
mask = (a[:, 3] == True)
a = a[mask, :]
"remove unnecessary redundant columns "
a = np.delete(a, 2, 1)
a = np.delete(a, 2, 1)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[1. 1.]
 [0. 2.]
 [1. 4.]
 [0. 6.]
 [1. 7.]]
```

What do you think?

Comment: grouping consecutive (sorted) values is a lot easier.  `unique` can handling a more general case, but it to uses sorting.

Comment: @hpaulj - thank you for hint but in my case i can not sort.

Answer (score 5):

You can compute the indices where the value changes:

```
idx = np.where(np.diff(a[:, 0])!=0)[0]

out = a[np.r_[0, idx+1]]
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 4],
       [0, 6],
       [1, 7]])
```

##### minimum per group

I initially misread and thought you wanted the minimum per group, you would need to combine to [`np.minimum.reduceat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html):

```
idx = np.where(np.diff(a[:, 0])!=0)[0]
out = np.minimum.reduceat(a, np.r_[0, idx+1], axis=0)
```

Example:

```
l1 = [1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1]
l2 = [1,0,3,2,4,5,6,7]
a = np.array([l1, l2]).T

idx = np.where(np.diff(a[:, 0])!=0)[0]
out = np.minimum.reduceat(a, np.r_[0, idx+1], axis=0)

array([[1, 0],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 4],
       [0, 6],
       [1, 7]])
```

##### sorting per group

Using [`lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html):

```
group = np.r_[0, np.cumsum(np.diff(a[:, 0])!=0)]
out = a[np.lexsort(np.c_[a[:, 1:], group].T)]
```

Example:

```
l1 = [1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1]
l2 = [1,0,3,2,4,5,6,7]
a = np.array([l1, l2]).T

group = np.r_[0, np.cumsum(np.diff(a[:, 0])!=0)]
# array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4])

out = a[np.lexsort(np.c_[a[:, 1:], group].T)]

array([[1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [1, 5],
       [0, 6],
       [1, 7]])
```

Comment: The main problem is that I can not sort rows. Your and my solution gave the same result, but your is shortest. Can someone timeit both? I can not I do not know how to.

Comment: This code: np.diff(a[:, 0])!=0 is clever solution when key is 0, 1 :P

Comment: @luki In don't understand the issue, my code gives you the expected output. Regarding `diff` this works for any value, not just 0/1 ;)

Comment: Yes. sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: So this works as you want?

Comment: Yes it fit to my case. Thank you.

Comment: @ mozway: I would like to mention that your solution is not universal. I tried your example to  ndarray without .T (for data like a = np.array([l1, l2]) not like a = np.array([l1, l2]).T ) and output is missing 0 index position.

Comment: @luki I don't understand your remark, but my code is intended to work on rows, not columns. If you want on columns you can indeed apply it on `a.T` then transpose again the output

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which is based on [`numpy.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html):

```
m = a[:, 0] != np.roll(a[:,0], 1)
m[0] = True
a[m, :]
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 4],
       [0, 6],
       [1, 7]])
```