# Fast interpolation of nodal values

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dataset like this:

Time | Node Label | Values

It is possible that at the same time there are 2 different values for the same node. I want to compare the values of these two rows and then substitute the first row with a new one. The second row has to be deleted.

Example with only 2 values:

```
Time | Node Label | Values

 1           3       10    5
 1           5       15    11
 1           3       -6    7
 2           3        8    4
 2           5        3    9
 2           3        1    1
```

It becomes:

```
Time | Node Label | Values

 1           3       2    6
 1           5       15   11
 2           3       4.5  2.5
 2           5        3   9
```

At the end I need that for a certain time I have each row that corresponds to a unique node label sorted in ascending order. For comparing the arrays and create the new to insert I’m simply utilizing the `np.mean` function.

I have come up with this solution:

```
time_col = data[:, 0]
label_col = data[:, 1]


unique_labels, label_indices = np.unique(label_col, return_inverse=True)
unique_times, time_indices = np.unique(time_col, return_inverse=True)

grouped_indices = np.ravel_multi_index((time_indices, label_indices), dims=(len(unique_times), len(unique_labels)))

grouped_data = [data[grouped_indices == i] for i in range(len(unique_times) * len(unique_labels))]
    
# apply a function to each group to select the row with the highest values
highest_value = np.array([np.mean(group, 0) for group in grouped_data])
    
# create a new numpy array from the highest_value array
data = np.concatenate([highest_value[:, :2], highest_value[:, 2:]], axis=1)
```

It works but it's terribly slow. Obviously because I have multiples explicit for loops and certainly I'm also looping through unnecessary elements. I can only use numpy library.

For example with this dataset it takes maybe hours: https://shorturl.at/myIY9

Comment: How are the values stored?  What's the data type of that column?  Why isn't it two separate columns?

Comment: Sorry for my poor formatting, I was trying to fix it. Thank you for your help. Data is a numpy array loaded from a .csv file. All the columns are imported as float numbers. The first two columns are respectively times and node labels. The remaining columns are nodal values

Answer (score 0):

First, you could try with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013778/is-there-any-numpy-group-by-function) solution.

After the groups are created, you can compute the mean of each group using an explicit for loop (which will still be better than evaluating `[data[grouped_indices == i] for i in range(len(unique_times) * len(unique_labels))]`).

Another solution, perhaps faster, would be to use `numpy.bincount` to group and also average the data.

Here’s an example

```
import numpy as np

# Create a sample 2D NumPy array
arr = np.array([[1, 3], [2, 4], [1, 5], [3, 5], [2, 6]])

# Get unique values and their corresponding indices
unq, inv = np.unique(arr[:, 0], return_inverse=True)

# Compute mean values for each group
weights = np.ones_like(inv) / inv.size
mean_arr = np.column_stack((unq, np.bincount(inv, weights=weights * arr[:, 1], minlength=len(unq)) / np.bincount(inv, weights=weights, minlength=len(unq))))

print(mean_arr)
```

In the case of an array with multiple value columns I think you should repeat the process for each column (without repeating the `unique` call).