# Identifying ones in each row and creating a list in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `A`. I am identifying ones in each row except the row number itself and creating a list. For example, in `A[0]`, the ones should be identified for locations `2,3,5` and not `0`. I present the current and expected output.

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]])

output = []
for i, row in enumerate(A):
    ones_indices = np.where(row == 1)[0]
    other_rows = np.arange(A.shape[0])
    other_rows = np.delete(other_rows, i)
    output.append([[i], other_rows.tolist()])

print(output)
```

The current output is

```
[[[0], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]], [[1], [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]], [[2], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]], [[3], [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]], [[4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]], [[5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]], [[6], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]], [[7], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11]], [[8], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11]], [[9], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11]], [[10], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11]], [[11], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]]
```

The expected output is

```
[[[0], [2,3,5]], [[1], [3,4,6]], [[2], [0,3,5]], [[3], [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6]], [[4], [1,3,6]], [[5], [0,2,3,7,8,10]], [[6], [1,3,4,8,9,11]], [[7], [5,8,10]], [[8], [5,6,7,9,10,11]], [[9], [6,8,11]], [[10], [5,7,8], [[11], [6,8,9]]]
```

Comment: hint: you never use `ones_indices`

Comment: Got it... but then I want to print in a specific format as shown in the expected output.

Comment: just use `output.append([[i], ones_indices[ones_indices != i].tolist()])` after getting `ones_indices`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numpy approach would be to [`fill_diagonal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html), then to use [`where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
np.fill_diagonal(A, 0)

row, idx = np.where(A==1)  # np.where(A) if only 0/1
```

Output:

```
(array([ 0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,
         4,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  7,  8,
         8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  9,  9,  9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11]),
 array([ 2,  3,  5,  3,  4,  6,  0,  3,  5,  0,  1,  2,  4,  5,  6,  1,  3,
         6,  0,  2,  3,  7,  8, 10,  1,  3,  4,  8,  9, 11,  5,  8, 10,  5,
         6,  7,  9, 10, 11,  6,  8, 11,  5,  7,  8,  6,  8,  9]))
```

If you really want nested lists:

```
np.fill_diagonal(A, 0)

out = [[[i], np.where(a==1)[0].tolist()] for i, a in enumerate(A)]
```

Or:

```
row, idx = np.where(A==1)

x = np.array_split(idx, np.where(row[1:]!=row[:-1])[0]+1)

out = [[[i], j.tolist()] for i,j in enumerate(x)]
```

Output:

```
[[[0], [2, 3, 5]],
 [[1], [3, 4, 6]],
 [[2], [0, 3, 5]],
 [[3], [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6]],
 [[4], [1, 3, 6]],
 [[5], [0, 2, 3, 7, 8, 10]],
 [[6], [1, 3, 4, 8, 9, 11]],
 [[7], [5, 8, 10]],
 [[8], [5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11]],
 [[9], [6, 8, 11]],
 [[10], [5, 7, 8]],
 [[11], [6, 8, 9]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is possibly a very convoluted way of doing this, but it works.

1. Fill the diagonal of A with zeros, since you don't want the index of the row the 1 is in.
2. Use `np.where` to get the locations of the 1s.
3. Use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43094244/12131013) to group by row.
4. Use list comprehension to combine the row number and the locations of the 1s.

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]])

# step 1
np.fill_diagonal(A, 0)

# step 2
a = np.vstack(np.where(A == 1)).T

# step 3
k = np.split(a[:, 1], np.unique(a[:, 0], return_index=True)[1][1:])

# step 4
res = [[[i], _k.tolist()] for i, _k in enumerate(k)]
```

With this, we have `res`:

```py
[[[0], [2, 3, 5]], [[1], [3, 4, 6]], [[2], [0, 3, 5]], [[3], [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6]], [[4], [1, 3, 6]], [[5], [0, 2, 3, 7, 8, 10]], [[6], [1, 3, 4, 8, 9, 11]], [[7], [5, 8, 10]], [[8], [5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11]], [[9], [6, 8, 11]], [[10], [5, 7, 8]], [[11], [6, 8, 9]]]
```

Comment: @mozway Yup, just saw your answer. I think my step 3 is a bit overkill. Probably better to go your route straight from `np.where` for each row.

Comment: The important step is `fill_diagonal` ;)

Comment: @mozway Agreed. That was the first thing I thought of when they said they didn't want the matching row index in there.

Comment: I'm not sure what OP really wants, but `np.where(A==1)` on the de-diagonalized array will be the most efficient. The question is whether or not the nested list structure is really needed.

Comment: @mozway It's a little strange. Once I have numpy arrays, I try to stick with them. And for this case, I don't like the jagged result. Better to use a `dict` if they want that relationship of row to indices.

Comment: I agree, thus my initial comment to stick to a flat array if possible. Btw, I think the `array_split` is not a bad idea, I added a variant using the output of `np.where`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way. I haven't checked the timings. Yet it gives the expected results.

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]])


# replace row indices with 0
np.fill_diagonal(A,0)
# create a 1D array 
b = np.arange(A.shape[0])
# multiply element wise with broadcasting 
c = np.multiply(A,b)
# get nonzero indices
rw, cl = c.nonzero()
# get [row,column] coordinates 
a = np.c_[rw,cl]
# groupby row and split
val = np.split(a[:,1], np.unique(a[:, 0], return_index=True)[1][1:])
# list comprehension 
out = [[[i],ar.tolist()] for i,ar in enumerate(val)]
print(out)

>> [[[0], [2, 3, 5]], [[1], [3, 4, 6]], [[2], [0, 3, 5]], [[3], [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6]], [[4], [1, 3, 6]], [[5], [0, 2, 3, 7, 8, 10]], [[6], [1, 3, 4, 8, 9, 11]], [[7], [5, 8, 10]], [[8], [5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11]], [[9], [6, 8, 11]], [[10], [5, 7, 8]], [[11], [6, 8, 9]]]
```