# Creating A List Of Dictionaries From Two Nested Lists, With Repeated Keys

Tags: python, pandas

I have two key/value inputs, both in the form of nested lists.  Any given key may have multiple values, as with K1 and K2 here:

```
key_in = [['K1', 'K1', 'K2', 'K3'], ['K1', 'K2', 'K2', 'K3']]
val_in = [['V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4'], ['V5', 'V6', 'V7', 'V8']]
```

I would like to merge / consolidate these into a list of nested dicts:

```
out = [{'K1': {'V1', 'V2'}, 'K2': {'V3'}, 'K3': {'V4'}}, {'K1': {'V5'}, 'K2': {'V6', 'V7'}, 'K3': {'V8'}}]
```

The closest thing I know how to do is `dict(zip(k, v)) for k, v in zip(key_in, val_in)`,  but that doesn't work for one-to-many key:vals.

In case this is something that could be done more efficiently in pandas, my ultimate goal is the creation of a dataframe like below.  (I mention efficiency since my source data is many millions of rows.)

```
      K1        K2       K3
0  {V1, V2}    {V3}     {V4}
1    {V5}    {V6, V7}   {V8}
```

Comment: Do you really want `out[0]['K1']` to be a set `{'V1', 'V2'}`?  Or do you want it to be a list `['V1', 'V2']`?

Comment: @wOw_python that doesn't quite do it.  First it splits `'V2'` into `{'V', '2'}`.  And the second K1 overwrites the first.  `[{'K1': {'V', '2'}, 'K2': {'V', '3'}, 'K3': {'V', '4'}}, {'K1': {'V', '5'}, 'K2': {'V', '7'}, 'K3': {'V', '8'}}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a *double zip-loop* to feed the nested dicts with sets and form your list :

```
from collections import defaultdict

out = []

for ink, inv in zip(key_in, val_in):
    d = defaultdict(set)
    for k, v in zip(ink, inv):
        d[k].add(v)
    out.append(dict(d))
```

Another variant, as suggest by @*mozway*, you can use :

```
out = []

for ink, inv in zip(key_in, val_in):
    d = {}
    for k, v in zip(ink, inv):
        d.setdefault(k, set()).add(v)
    out.append(d)
```

Output :

```
>>> print(out)

[{'K1': {'V1', 'V2'}, 'K2': {'V3'}, 'K3': {'V4'}},
 {'K1': {'V5'}, 'K2': {'V6', 'V7'}, 'K3': {'V8'}}]
```

To make a [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), you simply call the *constructor* :

```
>>> print(pd.DataFrame(out))

         K1        K2    K3
0  {V2, V1}      {V3}  {V4}
1      {V5}  {V7, V6}  {V8}
```

Comment: Wow, this is the fastest, i don't understand why it will faster than the numpy even I double clean the useless process.

Comment: Pandas reshaping is expensive, pure python is often the fastest in such cases

Comment: @Timeless you can also use `d = {}` and `d.setdefault(k, set()).add(v)`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as you said, pandas can be efficient for this type of problem with large datasets, since it uses vectorized operations that operate on entire columns/datasets at once.

```
import pandas as pd

key_in = [['K1', 'K1', 'K2', 'K3'], ['K1', 'K2', 'K2', 'K3']]
val_in = [['V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4'], ['V5', 'V6', 'V7', 'V8']]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'key': [k for sublist in key_in for k in sublist],
    'value': [v for sublist in val_in for v in sublist],
    'index': [i for i, sublist in enumerate(key_in) for _ in sublist]
})

df_grouped = df.groupby(['index', 'key'])['value'].apply(set).reset_index()

df_pivot = df_grouped.pivot(index='index', columns='key', values='value').reset_index(drop=True)

print(df_pivot)
```

Comment: Very nice and it gets @nplusone the sets he requested.  If one wanted lists so that multiple 'K1' -> 'V1' values would result in multiple 'V1' entries in the list then one need only replace `apply(set)` with `apply(list)`.  Again, very nice.

Answer (score 3):

Using pandas [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
(pd.DataFrame({'k': key_in, 'v': val_in})
   .explode(['k', 'v']).reset_index()
   .groupby(['index', 'k'])['v'].agg(set)
   .unstack('k')
)
```

Output:

```
k            K1        K2    K3
index                          
0      {V1, V2}      {V3}  {V4}
1          {V5}  {V6, V7}  {V8}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe we can use NumPy to improve the time efficiency, refer to [Is there any numpy group by function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013778/is-there-any-numpy-group-by-function/38015063#38015063) since you need improve time efficiency.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

key_in_list = [['K1', 'K1', 'K2', 'K3'], ['K1', 'K2', 'K2', 'K3']]
val_in_list = [['V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4'], ['V5', 'V6', 'V7', 'V8']]

key_in = np.concatenate([np.array(x) for x in key_in_list])
val_in = np.concatenate([np.array(x) for x in val_in_list])
index_in = np.concatenate([np.full(len(x), i) for i, x in enumerate(key_in_list)])

print("key_in:", key_in)
print("val_in:", val_in)
print("index_in:", index_in)
a = np.stack((index_in, key_in, val_in), axis=-1)
_, unique_idx = np.unique(a[:, :2], axis=0, return_index=True)
split_values = np.split(a[:, 2], np.unique(a[:, :2], axis=0, return_index=True)[1][1:])
```

And you can do the rest convert the dic to pandas, here is just example

```
df_grouped = pd.DataFrame({
    'index': a[unique_idx, 0],
    'key': a[unique_idx, 1],
    'value': split_values
}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

of course, you can sort before using this NumPy process.

Comment: what do you think of this @Malcolm

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which is based on `numpy`:

```
[{x[i]: set((np.array(y)[np.where(np.array(x) == x[i])[0]]))
  for i in range(len(x))} for x, y in zip(key_in, val_in)]
```

Output:

```
[{'K1': {'V1', 'V2'}, 'K2': {'V3'}, 'K3': {'V4'}},
 {'K1': {'V5'}, 'K2': {'V6', 'V7'}, 'K3': {'V8'}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way:

```
d = [{i:[] for i in set(k)} for k in key_in]

for e,(k,v) in enumerate(zip(key_in,val_in)):
    for k1,v1 in zip(k,v):
        d[e].get(k1).append(v1)
```

Output:

```
[{'K3': ['V4'], 'K2': ['V3'], 'K1': ['V1', 'V2']},
 {'K3': ['V8'], 'K2': ['V6', 'V7'], 'K1': ['V5']}]
```