# Find the minimum value for each unique key without using a for loop

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array with keys (e.g. `[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2]`) and an array with values (e.g. `[0.2, 0.6, 0.8, 0.4, 0.9, 0.3]`). I want to find the minimum value associated with each unique key without using a for loop. In this example, the answer is `{1: 0.2, 2: 0.3, 3: 0.4}`. I asked ChatGPT and New Bing but they keep giving me the wrong answer. So, is it really possible to do this without a for loop?

Edit 1: What I'm trying to achieve is the fastest speed. Also, in my case, most keys are unique. I considered using `np.unique` to acquire every key and then compute the min value for every key, but clearly it requires a for loop and a quadratic time. I also considered sorting the arrays by keys and apply `np.min` on the values of each key, but I doubt its efficiency when most keys are unique. Additionally, according to the comments, `pandas.DataFrame` has a `groupby` method which might be helpful, but I'm not sure if it's the fastest (perhaps I'm going to try on my own).

Edit 2: I don't necessarily need a `dict` as the output; it can be an array of unique keys and an array of min values, and the order of keys doesn't matter.

Comment: The answer to your question, as written, is “yes, it is possible”. However, I’m guessing that’s not actually what you want to know. It’d be helpful to know exactly what you’ve tried already and where it went wrong.

Comment: Are you using plain `numpy`, or `pandas`? The latter's `DataFrame`s are backed by `numpy` arrays, but it offers a lot more options for this sort of data manipulation.

Comment: how big are your numpy arrays? This can be done algorithmically efficiently with a simple python loop. As long as the arrays aren't enormous, it should still be pretty fast

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The size of the arrays is ~60k, but this operation is repeated tens of thousands of times.

Comment: [Is there any numpy group by function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013778/is-there-any-numpy-group-by-function) gives interesting answers to a very close (more general) question. Some solutions use loops, but are very fast compared to others. Especially the ones using Numba.

Comment: You could use `np.argsort()` on the array to find the indeces where making it sorterd, apply those indices to the array of keys, and then find the first index of each key. I'm not exactly sure how to do that without a loop, but it might help to start off from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The naive, python solution is something like:

```
result = {}

for key, value in zip(keys, values):
    current = result.get(key)
    if current is not None:
        result[key] = min(current, value)
    else:
        result[key] = value
```

It should be relatively fast.

If you really need to squeeze performance out of this, you should use `numba`

```
import numba

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def group_min(keys, values):
    result = {}

    for key, value in zip(keys, values):
        current = result.get(key)
        if current is not None:
            result[key] = min(current, value)
        else:
            result[key] = value

    return result
```

Make sure to read over the [numba docs](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/index.html) to understand how to squeeze as much performance as you can out of it.

Comment: I suspect the fastest approach is going to involve doing the above but with `numba`

Comment: @Soha Note that Numpy is mostly written in C, not C++ (though it does not impact much performance).

Comment: @Soha check out the new `numba` example, but note, `numba` has all sorts of options, like if you know the types ahead of time, you can use `njit` and it will potentially be faster if you provide a signature to the `numba.njit` decorator

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```py
keys = np.array([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2])
values = np.array([0.2, 0.6, 0.8, 0.4, 0.9, 0.3])

out = dict(
    map(
        lambda x: (x[0], np.min(x[1])),
        zip(
            (rv := np.unique(keys[(idx := np.argsort(keys))], return_index=True))[0],
            np.split(values[idx], rv[1][1:]),
        ),
    )
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{1: 0.2, 2: 0.3, 3: 0.4}
```

---

Quick benchmark:

```py
import numba
import perfplot


def get_dict_andrej(keys, values):
    return dict(
        map(
            lambda x: (x[0], np.min(x[1])),
            zip(
                (rv := np.unique(keys[(idx := np.argsort(keys))], return_index=True))[
                    0
                ],
                np.split(values[idx], rv[1][1:]),
            ),
        )
    )


def get_dict_juan(keys, values):
    result = {}

    for key, value in zip(keys, values):
        current = result.get(key, float("inf"))
        if key is not None:
            result[key] = min(current, value)
        else:
            result[key] = value

    return result


@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def get_dict_juan_numba(keys, values):
    result = {}

    for key, value in zip(keys, values):
        current = result.get(key)
        if current is not None:
            result[key] = min(current, value)
        else:
            result[key] = value

    return result


# compile the function
get_dict_juan_numba(
    np.array([1], dtype=np.int32),
    np.array([0.1], dtype=float),
)

np.random.seed(42)

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: (
        np.random.randint(1, n // 1.2, size=n, dtype=np.int32),
        np.random.random(size=n),
    ),
    kernels=[get_dict_andrej, get_dict_juan, get_dict_juan_numba],
    labels=["Andrej", "Juan", "Juan_numba"],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(10, 22)],
    xlabel="N",
    equality_check=None,
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
)
```

Creates this graph:

[image]

Comment: well, this is still a python-level loop ove rthe keys, no? I suspect the naive loop is faster, as long as the number of unique keys is close to the number of keys

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've created quick benchmark using `perfplot` (seems numpy is faster - but I think it depends on the input data (how many unique keys etc.))

Comment: It absolutely does! The op has already said that the size of unique(keys) is close to the size of keys

Comment: So try a benchmark with `np.random.randint(1, n, size=n, dtype=np.byte)`

Comment: AFAIK, hash-map based solutions tends to be less efficient than ones based on sorts when the number of unique value is close to the size of the array. This is because the hash-map start to be huge and not benefit much from the CPU-cache anymore. The actual item type (and even maybe the item values themselves) also matter for the sort since Numpy uses a radix-sort for integers by default.

Comment: @JérômeRichard interesting. If the OP wants another kind of output, that may be better then

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've updated the benchmark (with `n // 1.2` - to leave some room) and yes, even the plain python version is faster (numba version fastest :)

Comment: yeah, in any realistic scenario like this, I just reach for `numba`. Especially when there is a straightforward single-pass solution. I am curious about the considerations @JérômeRichard brings up, though. I liked and upvoted this answer, btw, just to be clear

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't necessarity need a dict as output. I've updated the question.

Comment: @Soha I think you can shave some time off the solution in this answer then, but note the performance of the naively JITed function

Comment: @Soha The `numba` version will be the fastest even in this case :)

Answer (score 2):

```
keys = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2]
values = [0.2, 0.6, 0.8, 0.4, 0.9, 0.3]
dct = {}
#Iterate over the list 'keys'
for i,x in enumerate(keys):
    #if the elements of list 'keys' present in the keys of the dct
    if x in dct.keys():
        '''
        find the value of the same index in the list 'values'. if this value
        is lesser than the previous value for the same key, then
        change to new value
        '''
        if values[i]<dct[x]: dct[x] = values[i]

        #If the new value is greater, leave unchanged
        else: pass
    '''
    if the element of list 'keys' not present in the keys of the dct
    get the element of the same index from the list values and allocate
    to its key in the dct
    '''
    else: dct[x] = values[i]
print(dct)

#output : {1: 0.2, 2: 0.3, 3: 0.4}
```

Comment: this only *happens* to work, it doesn't keep track of the association of keys and values, it will be wrong in other cases. e.g., using the same keys, `values = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]`

Comment: This doesn't work if the min value for key 1 happens to be something like 2.0

Comment: @vs07, It works. I checked by making min value 2.0 and apart from this I added a two in the keylist. Same in value list. Pl see the (screenshot)[https://imgur.com/DiN8Lcq]

Comment: Try running your code with keys remaining the same and values = `[2.0, 0.6, 0.8, 0.4, 0.9, 0.3]`. Edit: typo

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga once the dct is created with a separate variable name, the association is made and we can use it anywhere. I tried the output with print(dct[2]).
Are you telling this since I used set().Setting is used just in one step.

Comment: @vs07, It works. In the question, they are not worried about the values beyond the max-value of the keys. 2.0 is much bigger than 0.6,0.8 and 0.4

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga their requirement itself is such that they don't want higher values. If at all you want the association for all values, you can create another dict before taking the unique value.

Comment: @SuramuthuR try it with the example `values` input I gave in the original comment. It gives an answer of `{1: 0.1, 2: 0.2, 3: 0.3}` but the correct answer is `{1: 0.1, 2: 0.2, 3: 0.4}`

Comment: I will also add, your solution mutates the inputs, which is generally not a good practice

Comment: Again, it doesn't work. Try using `values = [1.0, 0.6, 0.8, 0.4, 0.9, 2.0]`. Also, it's definitely possible to do this without looping, as the other answers did.

Comment: @vs07 It works. There are one 1, three twos and two threes. So mini value of these are 0.4, 0.6 and 1.0 respectively. This is the output:  
{1: 0.4, 2: 0.6, 3: 1.0}

Comment: you seem to be misunderstanding the question. the min value of the key 3 is not 1, it is 0.4 (as it is between 0.4 and 0.9)

Comment: @vs07, Thank you. I understood the question wrongly. Now I've edited. Please check.

Comment: This is much better! And, it performs in linear time, which is pretty similar to the accepted answer. Nice work!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the dictionary constructor on a sorted list of tuples:

```
keys = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2]
vals = [0.2, 0.6, 0.8, 0.4, 0.9, 0.3]

minVals = dict(sorted(zip(keys,vals),reverse=True))

print(minVals)

{3: 0.4, 2: 0.3, 1: 0.2}
```

The dictionary will only keep the last value for each key which (because of the sort) will be the smallest for that key.

*Note that this will work faster on regular Python lists than numpy arrays because they don't need to go through value conversions*

Answer (score 0):

A pure numpy, no (python) loops solution based on np.ufunc.reduceat

```py
def pivot_index_reduceat(keys: np.ndarray) -> tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    """
    Prepare indices for a `np.ufunc.reduceat` like aggregate driver.

    Returns
    -------
    unique: np.ndarray
       The unique sorted keys.
    pindices: np.ndarray
        The sorting indices for `keys`. This permutation index needs be
        applied to the values array.
    reduce_splits: np.ndarray
        The `reduceat` split indices.
    """
    permute = np.argsort(keys, kind="stable")
    keys_sorted = keys[permute]
    flag = np.empty(keys.size, np.bool_)
    flag[0] = True  # special fixed first index
    # flag where consecutive keys_sorted are different
    np.not_equal(keys_sorted[:-1], keys_sorted[1:], out=flag[1:])
    rindices = np.flatnonzero(flag)  # the reduction indices
    ukeys = keys_sorted[rindices]
    return ukeys, permute, rindices


def group_by_agg(keys, values, ufunc: np.ufunc) -> tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    """
    Group by `keys` and aggregate `values` using `ufunc`
    """
    keys = np.asarray(keys)
    values = np.asarray(values)
    ukeys, permute, reduce_splits = pivot_index_reduceat(keys)
    values_sorted = values[permute]
    agg = ufunc.reduceat(values_sorted, reduce_splits)
    return ukeys, agg
```

```py
print(dict(zip(*group_by_agg([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2], [0.2, 0.6, 0.8, 0.4, 0.9, 0.3], np.minimum))))
```

```
{1: 0.2, 2: 0.3, 3: 0.4}
```

It's faster then a pure python loop, but lags behind a numba yeeted loop (it's a N*logN + multiple linear passes vs single linear pass)