# Get the index locations of values in tensor B that are present within tensor A

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, vectorization

I am essentially looking for a completely vectorized way to take a tensor B: `[1, 2, 3, 9]`, and tensor A: `[1,2,3,3,2,1,4,5,9]`, and for every value in tensor B, find its index locations in tensor A, so that the output would be something like: `[[0,5], [1,4], [2,3], [-1,8]]` (though it is fine if it is one dimensional as long as I can retrieve the information of which index's correspond to which values in tensor B), where each row corresponds to a value in tensor B, where the column values are the indices of occurrence of that given value within A.

This approach works:

```
def vectorized_find_indices(A, B):
    # Expand dimensions of A for broadcasting
    A_expanded = A[:, None, None]

    # Compare B with expanded A to create a boolean mask
    mask = (B == A_expanded)

    # Get the indices where A matches B
    indices = torch.where(mask, torch.arange(A.size(0), device=A.device)[:, None, None], torch.tensor(-1, device=A.device))

    # Reshape the indices to match the shape of B with an additional dimension for indices
    result = indices.permute(1, 2, 0)

    return result
```

But the tensors that I use are far too large for broadcasting to work, so I am constrained even more.

I have also tried several ways simpler ways like `searchsorted` and I found this solution: `(A[..., None] == B).any(-1).nonzero()`, which is close but not sufficient, as indices returned are no longer directly attached to the values.  For example, the above code snippet will return: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8]`, which are indeed the correct indices of where matches are found, but the information is no longer nested within a second dimension that ties it to its corresponding value like I need, but I am quite unfamiliar with pytorch so maybe something it is possible to get this information back somehow and reconstruct it using this information?

Comment: Are those the shapes of the tensors?

Comment: @jared No they are just examples with a couple values, everything is one dimensional besides the output example which I gave a second dimension to for separation of the found indices.

Comment: Then what are the two added dimensions for when broadcasting? You should only need to add one dimension if they are all 1D.

Comment: @jared Oh ya, my tensor B used to be two dimensional, but I was able to simplify it to get rid of it, so I suppose the function I provided is outdated in design, but it still seems to work when B is only a single dimension too.

Comment: I recommend updating your question with more current code and providing a full example along with the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a way to do this without either broadcasting A along B or doing a for loop over B to reduce memory overhead.

One solution might be

```py
overlap_idxs = (a.unsqueeze(1) == b).nonzero()

output = [[] for i in b]

for (a_idx, b_idx) in overlap_idxs:
    output[b_idx].append(a_idx.item())

output
>[[0, 5], [1, 4], [2, 3], [8]]
```

Alternatively with a python-level loop over b:

```py
output = []

for _b in b:
    idxs = (a==_b).nonzero().squeeze().tolist()
    if type(idxs) != list:
        idxs = [idxs]
        
    output.append(idxs)
    
output
>[[0, 5], [1, 4], [2, 3], [8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given an input `B = np.array([1, 2, 3, 9])` and `A = np.array([1,2,3,3,2,1,4,5,9])`, in order to make the algorithm fully vectorizable, I'd proceed like that:

Define `indices` as a grid of shape `(len(B), len(A), 2)` in order that, for each `i` and `j`, `indices[i,j] = [i, j]`:

```
indices = np.moveaxis(np.c_[np.meshgrid(np.arange(len(A)), np.arange(len(B)))], 0, -1)
```

Once you have the indices you can filter them to retrieve all couples `[i,j]` that satisfy `A[i]==B[j]`:

```
found = indices[B[:,None]==A[None,:]]
#array([[0, 0],
#       [5, 0],
#       [1, 1],
#       [4, 1],
#       [2, 2],
#       [3, 2],
#       [8, 3]])
```

Each row in this matrix is a couple of matching element's indices: e. g. `[0,0]` means that `A[0]==B[0]`, `[5,0]` means that `A[5]==B[0]`, `[8,3]` means `A[8]==B[3]` and so on.

Once that you have this data it's up to you how to organize the information. Since your desired output is something like `[[0,5], [1,4], [2,3], [-1,8]]`, I'd use the `group_by` vectorized function proposed for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77150915) and written by @[Carlos Pinzón](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3671939/carlos-pinz%C3%B3n):

```
output = group_by(found[:,1], lambda idx: found[idx,0])
#array([array([0, 5]), array([1, 4]), array([2, 3]), array([8])], dtype=object)
```

I attach the `group_by` function for completeness:

````
def group_by(by, func=lambda idx: idx, transform=False, equal_nan=True):
    """
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/77150915
    Groups by the unique values of `by`, calls `func` on each group of
    indices and returns the combined results as a numpy array.
    If `transform=True` the output has as many rows as x (like pandas "transform"),
    and as many rows as unique values in x otherwise (like pandas "apply"),
    ```
    # Examples:
    x = np.array([1, 3, 1, 2, 3])
    y = np.array([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
    print(group_by(x)) # [array([0, 2]) array([3]) array([1, 4])]
    means = group_by(x, lambda idx: np.mean(y[idx]))
    print(means) # [4.  2.  2.5]
    means = group_by(x, lambda idx: np.mean(y[idx]), transform=True)
    print(means) # [4.  2.5 4.  2.  2.5]
    mins, maxs = group_by(x, lambda idx: [np.min(y[idx]), np.max(y[idx])]).T
    print(mins, maxs) # [3 2 1] [5 2 4]
    for idx in group_by(x):
        print(x[idx[0]], y[idx]) # 1 [5 3]; 2 [2]; 3 [4 1]
    ```
    """
    _, invs, cnts = np.unique(
        by, return_counts=True, return_inverse=True, axis=0, equal_nan=equal_nan
    )
    idxs = np.split(np.argsort(by), np.cumsum(cnts)[:-1])
    out = [func(idx) for idx in idxs]
    if transform:
        out = [out[invs[i]] for i in range(len(by))]
    try:
        out = np.array(out)
    except:
        out = np.array(out, dtype=object)
    return out
````

Answer (score 0):

If `A` and `B` are each 1D arrays and you want the indices of their common values, you can broadcast the equal check and then collapse the result using an OR for the corresponding dimension (this can be done using `any` and specifying the axis).

```py
import numpy as np

B = np.array([1, 2, 3, 9])
A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 9])

equal = A[:,None] == B[None,:]
A_indices = np.nonzero(equal.any(1))[0]
B_indices = np.nonzero(equal.any(0))[0]
print(A_indices)  # [0 1 2 3 4 5 8]
print(B_indices)  # [0 1 2 3]
```