# 2D numpy array: groupby and average

Tags: python

I have two-

column text file like this:

1 0.0169

1 0.0013

2 0.0070

2 0.0181

2 0.0008

2 0.0014

2 0.0005

4 0.0084

4 0.0154

5 0.0075

5 0.0171

5 0.0038

5 0.0115

5 0.0105

5 0.0094

6 0.0098

6 0.0129

7 0.0085

7 0.0097

7 0.0046

7 0.0021

7 0.0151

7 0.0117

...

that I read into 2D numpy array:

G = np.loadtxt('2d.txt')

I would like to group by the first column and

replace 2nd column by average value:

1 (0.0169+0.0013)/2

2 (0.0070+0.0181+0.008+0.0014+0.0005)/4

4 ...

5 ...

...

What is the most elegant way of doing it (a one-liner)?

Of course, I could read-in the file, loop over it, do the calculations, etc

but I would like a one line numpy command that returns the transformed

2D numpy array ...

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to do this is to use `pandas` as it implements a `group_by` method that allows aggregation such as mean:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(G, columns=["key", "val"])
df.groupby("key", as_index=False).mean().to_numpy()
```

Result:

```
array([[1.00000000e+00, 9.10000000e-03],
       [2.00000000e+00, 5.56000000e-03],
       [4.00000000e+00, 1.19000000e-02],
       [5.00000000e+00, 9.96666667e-03],
       [6.00000000e+00, 1.13500000e-02],
       [7.00000000e+00, 8.61666667e-03]])
```

For alternatives, including a fairly obfuscated numpy-only options see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43094244/16173463

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using pandas as it has a `groupby` and `mean` functionality exactly for this.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.loadtxt('2d.txt')

df = pd.DataFrame(data = data)

# group by first column (index 0) and calculate mean
print(df.groupby([0]).mean())
```